# Summarise rows by omitting NA

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset that contains multiple rows per `sample`. Each row contains data that were collected in different measurements (every measurement = 1 row). Not all data were collected in every measurement, meaning that there are many `NA` values:

```
sample <- c("sample1", "sample1", "sample2", "sample2", "sample3", "sample3")
value1<- c(1, 5, 7, NA, NA, 3)
value2 <- c(1, 5, 5, NA, NA, 5)
value3 <- c(13, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA)
myinput <- data.frame(sample, value1, value2, value3)

> myinput
   sample value1 value2 value3
1 sample1      1      1     13
2 sample1      5      5     NA
3 sample2      7      5      7
4 sample2     NA     NA     NA
5 sample3     NA     NA     NA
6 sample3      3      5     NA
```

I would like to summarise these rows together, by replacing `NA` with existing values for every `sample`, where they exist. If the rows contradict each other (e.g. `sample1`), they should be left unchanged and not summarised. This is the desired output:

```
> myoutput
   sample value1 value2 value3
1 sample1      1      1     13
2 sample1      5      5     NA
3 sample2      7      5      7
4 sample3      3      5     NA
```

Thanks!

**Edit**: I changed the example in response to the question by margusl (fair point). If there are contradictory values (as in `sample1`), it would be best if the rows were left unchanged.

Comment: Can't you just take the column totals by sample, with na.rm=T?

Comment: What if there are values from multiple measurements, i.e if you change first row from `NA, NA, 13` to `1, 2, 13`?

Comment: This is mostly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272 (multiple functions). The unique portion is that your "summary" is akin to "collapse to non-NA values" where possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a helper function that (for example) keeps a value if there is a single non-missing value:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sample <- c("sample1", "sample1", "sample2", "sample2", "sample3", "sample3")
value1<- c(NA, 5, 7, NA, NA, 3)
value2 <- c(NA, 5, 5, NA, NA, 5)
value3 <- c(13, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA)
myinput <- tibble(sample, value1, value2, value3)

collapse_na <- function(x) {
  not_na <- x[!is.na(x)]
  if (length(not_na) != 1L) return(NA)
  not_na
}

myinput |>
  summarize(across(starts_with("value"), collapse_na), 
            .by = sample)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   sample  value1 value2 value3
#>   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 sample1      5      5     13
#> 2 sample2      7      5      7
#> 3 sample3      3      5     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `summarise` and `across` we could use `filter` with `if_all`.

"across() is very useful within summarise() and mutate(), but it’s hard to use it with filter() because it is not clear how the results would be combined into one logical vector. So to fill the gap, we’re introducing two new functions if_all() and if_any()." https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/

```
library(dplyr)

myinput %>% 
  filter(!if_all(-sample, ~ is.na(.)))
```

```
 sample value1 value2 value3
1 sample1      1      1     13
2 sample1      5      5     NA
3 sample2      7      5      7
4 sample3      3      5     NA
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it should be `summarise` but just sort of subset, e.g.,

```
> myinput[rowMeans(!is.na(myinput[-1])) > 0, ]
   sample value1 value2 value3
1 sample1      1      1     13
2 sample1      5      5     NA
3 sample2      7      5      7
6 sample3      3      5     NA
```