# Concatenating strings in a column by id

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a tibble that looks something like this :

```
  dep_code dep_color message               
    <chr>        <int> <chr>                 
  1 10               1  One                  
  2 10               1  NA                   
  3 10               1  Two                  
  4 10               1  NA                   
  5 10               1  Four                
  6 10               1  NA                   
  7 11               1  NA                   
  8 11               1  Three                  
  9 11               1  NA                   
 10 11               1  NA                   
 11 11               1  NA                   
 12 11               1  NA                   
 13 12               1  NA                   
 14 12               1  NA                   
 15 12               1  NA                   
 16 12               1  NA                   
 17 12               1  NA                   
 18 12               1  NA
```

As you can see, it’s looking like long data. I’d like to sort of widen it, but while concatenating the strings contained in the message column for each id. It’d also be great if I could fill empty cells with a custom message. It would end up looking something like this :

```
  dep_code dep_color message               
    <chr>        <int> <chr>                 
  1 10               1  OneTwoFour
  2 11               1  Three                   
  3 12               1  No message
```

Any idea how I could go with this ? I’ve looked at various functions but found none that looked like they could deal with that.

Tried functions like summarise and pivot_wider. I’m not sure if they’re fit for this sort of thing or if it’s that I don’t yet know how to use them well enough. I’ve been looking [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958/collapse-concatenate-aggregate-a-column-to-a-single-comma-separated-string-w), but didn’t manage to get anything working. It’s looking like the (seemingly useful) summarise function is deprecated ?

Thanks if you can help !

Answer (score 3):

This is effectively "summarize by group"<sup>1</sup> with a custom function.

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
quux |>
  summarize(
    message = c(Filter(nzchar, paste(na.omit(message), collapse = "")), 
                "No message")[1],
   .by=c(dep_code, dep_color)
  )
#   dep_code dep_color    message
# 1       10         1 OneTwoFour
# 2       11         1      Three
# 3       12         1 No message
```

## base R

```r
aggregate(
  message ~ dep_code + dep_color, data = quux,
  FUN = function(z) c(Filter(nzchar, paste(na.omit(z), collapse = "")), "No message")[1],
  na.action = na.pass)
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(quux)[, .(message = c(Filter(nzchar, paste(na.omit(message), collapse = "")), "No message")[1]),
                    by = .(dep_code, dep_color)]
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(dep_code = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), dep_color = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), message = c("One", NA, "Two", NA, "Four", NA, NA, "Three", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"))
```

---

P.S.

1. Good references for "summarize by group":

   - [Calculate the mean by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272)
   - [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272)
   - [Apply several summary functions (sum, mean, etc.) on several variables by group in one call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272)

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for answering, this worked well for me. I’m told when running summarize() that the function is deprecated. Could that be a problem later if I run my code with a newer version of dplyer ?

Comment: Why do you think it's deprecated? That's news to me.

Comment: According to [`?summarize`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html), the way that you might see "deprecated" using `summarize` is returning  variable number of rows per group, in which case `reframe` may be more appropriate. If you're seeing that here, then something in your data is unlike the sample data.

Comment: Yeah, there was something wrong with my code, which caused duplicates. I fixed and now I’m not told anything about it being deprecated anymore. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution:

```
df <- split(df, df$dep_code) |>
    lapply(FUN = function(x) {
        messages <- paste(na.omit(x$message), collapse = "")
        
        if (messages == "") {
            messages <- "No Message"
        }
        
        data.frame(
            dep_code = unique(x$dep_code),
            dep_color = unique(x$dep_color),
            message = messages
        )
    })

do.call(rbind, df)
```

Result:

```
   dep_code dep_color    message
10       10         1 OneTwoFour
11       11         1      Three
12       12         1 No Message
```