# Using mutate to paste a column name if a condition is matched

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, rowwise

Let's say I work in a psychological context and I'm wondering how many risk factors a patient has. After that, I would like to list all the risks and then discover the most prevalent risk (mode). I'm thinking on use `mutate` and then `paste0` and get the `colname` if the value of the row is "risk". However, I'm having a hard time with that.
any help is appreaciated.

[image: risk]

Code is below:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(
  patient = seq(1:60),
  cancer = c("risk","ok"), 
  blood_pres = c("risk", "ok"),
  low_education = c("risk","ok")
) 

df = df %>% mutate(how_many_risks =
                     rowSums(. == "risk"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's come up with some more interesting data.

```r
set.seed(43)
df <- data.frame(patient = 1:10, cancer = sample(c("risk","ok"), size=10, replace=TRUE), blood_pres = sample(c("risk","ok"), size=10, replace=TRUE), low_education = sample(c("risk","ok"), size=10, replace=TRUE))
df
#    patient cancer blood_pres low_education
# 1        1     ok       risk          risk
# 2        2     ok       risk          risk
# 3        3     ok         ok            ok
# 4        4   risk       risk          risk
# 5        5     ok         ok          risk
# 6        6   risk       risk            ok
# 7        7     ok         ok            ok
# 8        8     ok       risk            ok
# 9        9     ok         ok            ok
# 10      10   risk       risk          risk
```

From here, we'll pivot, summarize, then join back onto the original data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -patient, values_to = "risk") %>%
  filter(risk == "risk") %>%
  summarize(howmany = n(), risks = toString(name), .by = patient) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = "patient") %>%
  mutate(howmany = coalesce(howmany, 0))
#    patient cancer blood_pres low_education howmany                             risks
# 1        1     ok       risk          risk       2         blood_pres, low_education
# 2        2     ok       risk          risk       2         blood_pres, low_education
# 3        3     ok         ok            ok       0                              <NA>
# 4        4   risk       risk          risk       3 cancer, blood_pres, low_education
# 5        5     ok         ok          risk       1                     low_education
# 6        6   risk       risk            ok       2                cancer, blood_pres
# 7        7     ok         ok            ok       0                              <NA>
# 8        8     ok       risk            ok       1                        blood_pres
# 9        9     ok         ok            ok       0                              <NA>
# 10      10   risk       risk          risk       3 cancer, blood_pres, low_education
```

(Note that `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer is required to use `.by=`. If you have an older dplyr and will not update, shift to using `group_by(patient)` instead of `.by=patient`.)

Something you may want to consider: unless this is solely for presentation tables, it is occasionally advantageous to have `risks` as a list-column instead of a comma-delimited string. To do this, just replace `toString` with `list`, and while it may *render* the same on the console, it will allow things like set-ops on it (though normal column/vector operations may not work as you expect):

```r
out <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -patient, values_to = "risk") %>%
  filter(risk == "risk") %>%
  summarize(howmany = n(), risks = list(name), .by = patient) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = "patient") %>%
  mutate(howmany = coalesce(howmany, 0))
out
#    patient cancer blood_pres low_education howmany                             risks
# 1        1     ok       risk          risk       2         blood_pres, low_education
# 2        2     ok       risk          risk       2         blood_pres, low_education
# 3        3     ok         ok            ok       0                              NULL
# 4        4   risk       risk          risk       3 cancer, blood_pres, low_education
# 5        5     ok         ok          risk       1                     low_education
# 6        6   risk       risk            ok       2                cancer, blood_pres
# 7        7     ok         ok            ok       0                              NULL
# 8        8     ok       risk            ok       1                        blood_pres
# 9        9     ok         ok            ok       0                              NULL
# 10      10   risk       risk          risk       3 cancer, blood_pres, low_education
```

If this data were a tibble (`tbl_df`) instead, the same data would present as

```r
tibble(out)
# # A tibble: 10 × 6
#    patient cancer blood_pres low_education howmany risks    
#      <int> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>           <dbl> <list>   
#  1       1 ok     risk       risk                2 <chr [2]>
#  2       2 ok     risk       risk                2 <chr [2]>
#  3       3 ok     ok         ok                  0 <NULL>   
#  4       4 risk   risk       risk                3 <chr [3]>
#  5       5 ok     ok         risk                1 <chr [1]>
#  6       6 risk   risk       ok                  2 <chr [2]>
#  7       7 ok     ok         ok                  0 <NULL>   
#  8       8 ok     risk       ok                  1 <chr [1]>
#  9       9 ok     ok         ok                  0 <NULL>   
# 10      10 risk   risk       risk                3 <chr [3]>
```

We can do things directly such as check the lengths of each row in that column; or check quickly for exact set-membership:

```r
lengths(out$risks)
#  [1] 2 2 0 3 1 2 0 1 0 3

sapply(out$risks, `%in%`, x = "cancer")
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Granted, both of those can be done with regex, but .. if the names have any ambiguity, regex carries a little overhead.

Comment: I reckon this is just better off structured as a long dataset. Then you can count the number of unique patients per risk factor, the number of risk factors per patient, the intersecting sets of patients with cancer and blood_pres, etc etc using standard 'tidy' logic.

Comment: This is a very nice answer. However, we miss the "how many risks" column.  could you please help me to have "how may risks" and "which risks" ?

Comment: Sure, I added the `howmany = n()` part. If you aren't familiar with summarizing by group, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272 (multiple functions).

Answer (score 2):

The `c_across()` function is what you are missing. Using your example data:

```
risk_factors <- c('cancer', 'blood_pres', 'low_education')

df <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(how_many_risks = sum(c_across(all_of(risk_factors)) == "risk"),
         what_risks = paste0(risk_factors[which(c_across(all_of(risk_factors)) == "risk")], collapse = ";")) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

You could add an extra line of logic to report the empty cases as 'none' (as in your example) with:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(what_risks = if_else(what_risks == "", "none", what_risks))
```

based on the OP's comments, assuming the variables all begin with "risk" and no longer requiring the name vector:

```
df <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(how_many_risks = sum(c_across(starts_with("risk")) == "risk"),
         what_risks = paste0(colnames(.)[which(c_across(starts_with("risk")) == "risk")], collapse = ";")
         ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Almost. Can we replace the "risk_factor" vector for columns in my dataset ? (if the column starts_with("risk") ? [In my previous example, it would be smth like `all_off(cancer, blood_pressu, low_education)`

Comment: easy! `starts_with("risk")` inside `c_across()`. Then you don't need the vector of column names at all. However, be sure to name your new mutate columns with something that doesn't start with 'risk'

Comment: I think I'm almost there. Could you please help me with this? `mutate(what_risks = paste0(which(c_across(all_of(starts_with("cutoff_")) == "risk")), collapse = ";"))` (my columns with the "risk" information all starts_with "

Comment: see the edit -- you don't need `all_of()` inside `c_across()` if you use a different selecting function (i.e. `starts_with("risk")`)

Answer (score 1):

I think a single `mutate` call is enough for this operation (data taken from @r2evans).

Here I didn't use `rowwise`, but used `sapply` to iterate through the rows to find values matching "risk".

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(43)
df <- data.frame(patient = 1:10, cancer = sample(c("risk","ok"), size=10, replace=TRUE), blood_pres = sample(c("risk","ok"), size=10, replace=TRUE), low_education = sample(c("risk","ok"), size=10, replace=TRUE))

df %>% 
  mutate(how_many_risks = rowSums(. == "risk"),
         which_risks = ifelse(how_many_risks == 0, "no risk", paste0(sapply(1:nrow(df), \(x) paste(colnames(df[x, -1])[df[x, -1] == "risk"], collapse = ", ")))))

   patient cancer blood_pres low_education how_many_risks                       which_risks
1        1     ok       risk          risk              2         blood_pres, low_education
2        2     ok       risk          risk              2         blood_pres, low_education
3        3     ok         ok            ok              0                           no risk
4        4   risk       risk          risk              3 cancer, blood_pres, low_education
5        5     ok         ok          risk              1                     low_education
6        6   risk       risk            ok              2                cancer, blood_pres
7        7     ok         ok            ok              0                           no risk
8        8     ok       risk            ok              1                        blood_pres
9        9     ok         ok            ok              0                           no risk
10      10   risk       risk          risk              3 cancer, blood_pres, low_education
```

Answer (score 1):

One More solution using dplyr `c_across` and `across` both.  In this strategy you do not have to create explicit vector of risk_names.

```r
library(tidyverse)


df %>% 
  mutate(across(cancer:low_education, ~ifelse(. == 'risk', cur_column(), "No Risk"), .names = "{.col}_N")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(which_risks = paste(unique(c_across(ends_with("_N"))), collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  select(-ends_with("_N"))
#> # A tibble: 60 × 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    patient cancer blood_pres low_education how_many_risks which_risks           
#>      <int> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>                 
#>  1       1 risk   risk       risk                       3 cancer, blood_pres, l…
#>  2       2 ok     ok         ok                         0 No Risk               
#>  3       3 risk   risk       risk                       3 cancer, blood_pres, l…
#>  4       4 ok     ok         ok                         0 No Risk               
#>  5       5 risk   risk       risk                       3 cancer, blood_pres, l…
#>  6       6 ok     ok         ok                         0 No Risk               
#>  7       7 risk   risk       risk                       3 cancer, blood_pres, l…
#>  8       8 ok     ok         ok                         0 No Risk               
#>  9       9 risk   risk       risk                       3 cancer, blood_pres, l…
#> 10      10 ok     ok         ok                         0 No Risk               
#> # ℹ 50 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score -3):

```
risk_factors <- c('cancer', 'blood_pres', 'low_education')
```