# How to calculate column sum of column values based on condition from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, rowsum

I have dataframe

```
Category = c("Fixed","New" ,"Fixed" ,"Regular", "Fixed", "New", "New")
Day1 = c(313, NA,239, 341, 14,11,521)
Day2=c(113, 510,939, NA, 741, 141,541)
Day3=c(13, 5,3, 41, 74,NA, 520)
Day4 = c(41, 10,23, 34, 401,191,NA)
```

```
df <- data.frame(Category, Day1, Day2, Day3, Day4, check.names = FALSE)
```

For columns from `Day 1 to 4` I would like to potentially write a for loop and calculate the total sum of each `Day` with the condition on column `Category` where `Category = Fixed` and `Category = New`

**What i have attempted**

Subset the dataframe based on conditions

`subset_data <- df[(df$Category=='Fixed' | df$Category=='New')]`

then calculate the row sums for the `subset_data` for each day however at this point am unsure.

**what is the correct way to calculate the `Day 1 to 4` columns sums based on `Category =Fixed or New` column condition?**

The line of code  below attempts `colSums()` function but it returns an empty array.

`specific_sums <- colSums(subset_data[c("Day1")])`

Comment: First, your data is not numeric thus cannot be summed. Second, did you mean to say column sum instead of row sum? You have mixed the two and its unclear what you want

Comment: Third, your sample-data-code has a parsing error. Please try to use sample data/code when you give it to us in the question.

Comment: `aggregate(.~Category, type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE), sum)` should do the trick

Comment: @Onyambu thanks i have made correction it should column sums and values for `Day` are now numeric.

Comment: FYI, `df[(df$Category=='Fixed' | df$Category=='Fixed')]` is duplicative, assuming you meant one of those to be `'New'` then  it is better written as `df[df$Category %in% c('Fixed','New'),]`

Comment: With that, `colSums(subset_data[c("Day1")])` is not empty for me, so you must be doing something else.

Comment: Onyambu's comment (without the now-unnecessary `type.convert`) works, the only issue is that it provides the summary for `"Regular"` as well. You can remove that in the results by doing `aggregate(.~Category, df[df$Category %in% c('Fixed','New'),], sum)`. This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272 (multiple functions), please see those links for many more options for summarizing your data.

Comment: If you need a _combined_ sum of those two categories, then a simple approach is `sapply(df[df$Category %in% c('Fixed','New'), -1], sum)` to return a vector, one for each `Day#` in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` to do the aggregation. Invoke the `subset` parameter to only select the part that you want:

```
aggregate(.~Category, df, sum,subset = Category %in% c('New', 'Fixed'))

  Category Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4
1    Fixed  693 1793  126  465
2      New  842 1192  636  722
```

Comment: thanks i have tried this on the actual dataset instead of the dummy df given in the question but i am getting the error `Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate` these columns do have values except some of them are null but that should not stop from it from aggregating ?

Comment: I added `,na.rm=TRUE` to the solution but i am still getting the same error.  `aggregate(.~Category, df, sum,subset = Category %in% c('New', 'Fixed'),na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @Sam by default `aggregate` drops `NA` rows. if you have `NA` invoke the `na.action` parameter. ie `aggregate(.~Category, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE, subset = Category %in% c('New', 'Fixed'), na.action = identity)`