# multiple lines with same total, Average the total and input the data in one line

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data like this

```
Name id   total   
Abc  101, 500, 
Abc  101, 500, 
Def  102, 400, 
Def  102, 400, 
Def  102, 400,
```

I need like this

```
Abc 101 500
Def 102 400
```

```
  group_by(Employee.ID) %>% 
  summarise(Total.Bonus = mean(Total.Bonus)
```

&

```
  group_by(Employee.ID) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs = mean=mean(., na.rm = TRUE)), matches('^\\d+'))
```

Comment: (1) Your sample data names are different than the names in your suggested code, please keep the two consistent with each other. (2) `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarize(Bonus = mean(total))` works, the same (names notwithstanding) as your code. (3) `summarise_each` has been soft-deprecated for well over 4 years, your second block should instead be something like `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarize(across(matches("^\\d"), .fns = list(mean = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))))`, though `"^\\d+"` matches against column names starting with a digit, which is not suggested here and atypical to R processes.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarize(across(where(is.numeric), .fns = list(mean = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))))`?

Comment: This is effectively, "summarize by group", here are a few existing questions that give a lot more detail than my comments above: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12064202/3358272 (multiple functions). If all of this does not resolve your question, please [edit] your question, clarify your inconsistent data/code, and explain what doesn't work about what I've suggested.

Comment: `distinct(df)` should suffice here, as well.