# Reformatting data in R (huge amount of lines)

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape

Thanks in advance for your help.
I am using R and let's say that I have a datatable (or eventually a timeseries with zoo) with the following format:

```
Col1: time   Values
Day1 H1      Value
Day1 H2      Value
Day1 H3      Value
Day1 H4      Value

Day2 H1      Value
Day2 H2      Value
Day2 H3      Value
Day2 H4      Value

Day3 H1      Value
...
```

Let's say that I would like to construct a matrix with the following format:
Rows:Days

```
    H1       H2       H3       H4
D1  Values   Values   Values   Values
D2  Values   Values   Values   Values
D3  Values   Values   Values   Values
```

and also:

```
    average(H1,H2)       average(H3,H4)
D1  Values               Vales
D2  Values               Vales
D3  Values               Vales
```

In some languages such as C++ we would probably proceed with a double 'for' but I am not sure it is the best way to proceed here.
Thanks a lot, I am new to R and I am quite lost with the different logic (but very interesting one).

I have seen other questions on the topic but I am not clear at all.

Comment: The double loop with some for? I have like 200,000 lines so I am quite worried for the performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with some basic `reshape` work, and `aggregate()` or `within()` for the means:

First, some sample data is very helpful:

```
set.seed(1)
temp <- data.frame(Col1 = paste("Day", rep(1:4, each = 4), sep=""),
                   times = paste("H", rep(1:4, times = 4), sep=""),
                   Values = runif(16, min=0, max=10))
temp
#    Col1 times    Values
# 1  Day1    H1 2.6550866
# 2  Day1    H2 3.7212390
# 3  Day1    H3 5.7285336
# 4  Day1    H4 9.0820779
# 5  Day2    H1 2.0168193
# 6  Day2    H2 8.9838968
# 7  Day2    H3 9.4467527
# 8  Day2    H4 6.6079779
# 9  Day3    H1 6.2911404
# 10 Day3    H2 0.6178627
# 11 Day3    H3 2.0597457
# 12 Day3    H4 1.7655675
# 13 Day4    H1 6.8702285
# 14 Day4    H2 3.8410372
# 15 Day4    H3 7.6984142
# 16 Day4    H4 4.9769924
```

Second, use `reshape` to go from long to wide format

```
tempwide <- reshape(temp, direction = "wide", idvar="Col1", timevar="times")
tempwide
#    Col1 Values.H1 Values.H2 Values.H3 Values.H4
# 1  Day1  2.655087 3.7212390  5.728534  9.082078
# 5  Day2  2.016819 8.9838968  9.446753  6.607978
# 9  Day3  6.291140 0.6178627  2.059746  1.765568
# 13 Day4  6.870228 3.8410372  7.698414  4.976992
```

Third, use `rowMeans` on the desired subset of your columns. You can also use `aggregate` if you prefer, but this is a convenient way to transform your original `data.frame`.

```
tempwide <- within(tempwide, {
  mean.H1H2 <- rowMeans(tempwide[2:3])
  mean.H3H4 <- rowMeans(tempwide[4:5])
})
tempwide
#    Col1 Values.H1 Values.H2 Values.H3 Values.H4 mean.H3H4 mean.H1H2
# 1  Day1  2.655087 3.7212390  5.728534  9.082078  7.405306  3.188163
# 5  Day2  2.016819 8.9838968  9.446753  6.607978  8.027365  5.500358
# 9  Day3  6.291140 0.6178627  2.059746  1.765568  1.912657  3.454502
# 13 Day4  6.870228 3.8410372  7.698414  4.976992  6.337703  5.355633
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Do you have any prefered 'book' or 'pdf' for a beginner?

Comment: @user1677319, sorry, not really. Check out the [Contributed Documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html) page at CRAN. There are quite a few good guides there. Also, check out [CRAN Task Views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) were you can view a list of useful functions and packages according to whatever your area of study/analysis you generally do.

Comment: google or other forum groups are useful too, you just have to teach "your google" to search for right web-pages

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed many ways of doing this. You could use the `data.table` package for aggregation. Why use `data.table`? It's **fast** (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533438/why-is-plyr-so-slow)).

Leveraging off Ananda Mahto's answer, we step off at the `tempwide` point, creating `temp wide.table`.

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1)
temp <- data.frame(Col1 = paste("Day", rep(1:4, each = 4), sep=""),
                   times = paste("H", rep(1:4, times = 4), sep=""),
                   Values = runif(16, min=0, max=10))

tempwide <- reshape(temp, direction = "wide", idvar="Col1", timevar="times")

tempwide.table <- data.table(tempwide)

tempwide.table[, H1n2 := sum(Values.H1, Values.H2)/2, by=Col1]
tempwide.table[, H3n4 := sum(Values.H3, Values.H4)/2, by=Col1]
```

so, printing `tempwide.table` yields:

```
   Col1 Values.H1 Values.H2 Values.H3 Values.H4     H1n2     H3n4
1: Day1  7.176185  9.919061 3.8003518  7.774452 8.547623 5.787402
2: Day2  9.347052  2.121425 6.5167377  1.255551 5.734239 3.886144
3: Day3  2.672207  3.861141 0.1339033  3.823880 3.266674 1.978891
4: Day4  8.696908  3.403490 4.8208012  5.995658 6.050199 5.408230
```

The syntax is flexible, and for a many column mean, you'd probably want something like:

```
tempwide.table[, list(mean(sum(Values.H1, Values.H2)/2)), by=Col1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (with appropriate changes if its coming from a file and the days are not literally `Day1`, etc.):

```
Lines <- "Col1 times    Values
Day1    H1 2.6550866
Day1    H2 3.7212390
Day1    H3 5.7285336
Day1    H4 9.0820779
Day2    H1 2.0168193
Day2    H2 8.9838968
Day2    H3 9.4467527
Day2    H4 6.6079779
Day3    H1 6.2911404
Day3    H2 0.6178627
Day3    H3 2.0597457
Day3    H4 1.7655675
Day4    H1 6.8702285
Day4    H2 3.8410372
Day4    H3 7.6984142
Day4    H4 4.9769924"

library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, index = 1, split = 2, FUN = identity)
```

The result is:

```
> z
           H1        H2       H3       H4
Day1 2.655087 3.7212390 5.728534 9.082078
Day2 2.016819 8.9838968 9.446753 6.607978
Day3 6.291140 0.6178627 2.059746 1.765567
Day4 6.870228 3.8410372 7.698414 4.976992
```

See `?read.zoo` and `vignette("zoo-read")` for more info.