# Adding an ID or index column for plyr's subsets

Tags: r, plyr

Assume I have the data

```
item   cond      foo
   1      1 3.733333
   2      1 4.766667
   3      1 4.133333
   4      2 4.466667
   5      2 2.800000
   6      2 2.300000
```

I need to generate  a new column that uniquely identifies an `item` per `cond` value, so I'd like to get:

```
item   cond      foo  item_per_cond
   1      1 3.733333              1
   2      1 4.766667              2
   3      1 4.133333              3
   4      2 4.466667              1
   5      2 2.800000              2
   6      2 2.300000              3
```

I figured I'd go with something like this, but I have no idea what the `...` should be here?

```
ddply(d, .(cond), transform, ...)
```

Comment: @Henrik Indeed, the answer is there, thanks. Although I'm specific about asking for `plyr` here.

Comment: @slhck, `plyr` is obsolete, either use `ave`, `dplyr` or `data.table`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Can you point me to a reference that says `plyr` is obsolete? (Downvote because..?)

Comment: @slhck, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533438/why-is-plyr-so-slow) for starters

Comment: @DavidArenburg technically `plyr` isn't obsolete, but Hadley Wickham created `dplyr` as a [next iteration](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) of `plyr`; although it is still possible to use `plyr`, `dplyr` is much faster and more logical with the piping possibility. See also [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25865032/2204410) for a `dplyr` solution.

Comment: @Jaap, are you serious? Are just explaining me about `dplyr`? I'm well aware of `dplyr` and this is the exact reason why I mentioned it in my comment as a better alternative to `plyr`. There is nothing special in your answer and I provided plenty of these myself

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm sorry if you feel offended by my comment. That wasn't the purpose. I just wanted to give some more details. I'm also not claiming that my answer is special (it isn't, I've also given several of these myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `seq_along` with the column name:

```
ddply(d, .(cond), transform, item_per_cond = seq_along(item)
```

Comment: It's nice if you want to create grouped bar plots where you facet-wrap per condition and show `foo` as y value. Then you can use the new column as x-axis instead of the original one.

Answer (score 1):

As you are specifically interested in a `plyr` solution, you might want to consider the new `dplyr` package of Hadley Wickham as wel:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(cond) %>% mutate(item_per_cond = seq_along(item))
```

which gives the following result:

```
  item cond      foo item_per_cond
1    1    1 3.733333             1
2    2    1 4.766667             2
3    3    1 4.133333             3
4    4    2 4.466667             1
5    5    2 2.800000             2
6    6    2 2.300000             3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dplyr approach.

```
item <- c(1,1,2,3,5,1,2,2,2,5)
cond <- rep(c(1,2), each = 5)
value <- runif(10, 10, 20)

foo <- data.frame(item, cond, value, stringsAsFactors = F)

foo %>%
    group_by(cond) %>%
    mutate(index = dense_rank(item))

   item cond    value index
1     1    1 11.66528     1
2     1    1 18.22134     1
3     2    1 18.17833     2
4     3    1 16.58589     3
5     5    1 14.75184     4
6     1    2 11.65522     1
7     2    2 12.74313     2
8     2    2 17.17077     2
9     2    2 11.37193     2
10    5    2 12.43162     3
```

Comment: +1 dense_rank is new for me. nice.