# Faster alternatives to ddply and group_by

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, data.table, plyr

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to loop through a data.frame, `myData`, grouping by two columns, `c1` and `c2`.
Specifically I want to loop through each unique combination of `c1` and `c2` and apply a certain `customFunction` to other columns in `myData`. This `customFunction` depends on `someStatsFunction`, which outputs a `data.frame`.

I would typically use the function `plyr::ddply`, but my real dataset has over 18 million rows, and not surprisingly this is taking too long. So I decided to change the approach to a pipeline using `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::do`. Although using `dplyr` speeds up the problem (see minimal example below), it still takes quite some time. I heard that the [`data.table`](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#fast-looping-with-set) framework can speed things a lot (see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533438/why-is-plyr-so-slow)), but I have no idea how to use it. I was wondering if anyone would be able to translate my problem below using `data.table` so I can also benchmark it.

```
library(plyr)  
library(dplyr)  
library(rbenchmark)  

someStatsFunction  <-  function (x) {
    data.frame(name = 'something', mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), statx = sqrt(mean(abs(x)))/sd(x)^2)
}

customFunction  <-  function (data) {
    if (!all(sort(data$time) == data$time)) {
        stop('Column \'time\' is not ordered')
    }
    someStatsFunction(data$response)
}

myData  <-  data.frame(c1 = rep(rep(1:50, each = 30), 10), c2 = rep(rep(1:30, 50), 10), response = rnorm(30 * 50 * 10), time = 1:(30 * 50 * 10))

benchmark('testPlyr' = {
            testPlyr   <-  plyr::ddply(myData, .(c1, c2), customFunction)
          },
          'testDplyr' = {
            testDplyr  <-  myData %>% dplyr::group_by(c1,c2) %>% dplyr::do(customFunction(.))
          },
          replications = 3,
          columns      = c('test', 'replications', 'elapsed', 'relative', 'user.self', 'sys.self'))
```

Here's what I get for the output:

```
       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2 testDplyr            3   7.416     1.00     7.368    0.060
1  testPlyr            3   8.378     1.13     8.364    0.012
```

Thanks,
D

**UPDATE** after @minem's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51780728/2793521)

First, I did some fixing with my example above because the code was not correct.

Second, I expanded my minimal reproducible example above to better reflect (slightly) my situation. The `someStatsFunction` may depend on multiple columns from the data.table, and crunch a bunch of numbers based on some non-trivial combination of stats derived from these multiple columns. I also increased the size of `myData` (so the example below takes longer now if compared to the original one). Anyhow, I think I managed to replicate the output I would get from `plyr` or `dplyr`. It runs faster with data.table, which is really cool (see benchmarking below). However, the code seems a bit clumsy:

```
library(plyr)  
library(dplyr)  
library(data.table)  
library(rbenchmark)  

someStatsFunction  <-  function (y, x) {
    x    <-  as.integer(x)
    mod  <-  coef(summary(lm(y ~ x)))
    data.frame(stats1  = 'something',
             intercept = mod[1],
             slope     = mod[2],
             meanx     = mean(x),
             statx     = sqrt(mean(abs(x)))/sd(y)^2)
}

customFunction  <-  function (data) {
    if (!all(sort(data$time) == data$time)) {
        stop('Column \'time\' is not ordered')
    }
    someStatsFunction(y = data$response, x = data$time)
}

myData  <-  data.frame(c1 = rep(rep(1:50, each = 30), 1095), c2 = rep(rep(1:30, 50), 1095), response = rnorm(30 * 50 * 1095), time = rep(seq(as.Date('1981-01-01'), as.Date('1983-12-31'), by = '1 day'), each = 50*30))

benchmark('testPlyr' = {
            testPlyr   <-  plyr::ddply(myData, .(c1, c2), customFunction)
        },
          'testDplyr' = {
            testDplyr  <-  myData %>% dplyr::group_by(c1,c2) %>% dplyr::do(customFunction(.))
        },
          'testDtb' = {
            vNames   <-  c('stats1', 'intercept', 'slope', 'meanx', 'statx')
            dt       <- as.data.table(myData)
            testDtb  <- dt[order(time)][, 
            (vNames) := as.list(someStatsFunction(response, time)), 
            by = .(c1, c2)][, 
            head(.SD, 1), by = .(c1, c2)][, 
            c('response', 'time') := NULL, ]
        },
    replications = 3,
    columns      = c('test', 'replications', 'elapsed', 'relative', 'user.self', 'sys.self'))
```

Here's what I get for the output:

```
       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2 testDplyr            3  28.209    3.101    20.841    7.317
3   testDtb            3   9.098    1.000    10.958    0.385
1  testPlyr            3  28.224    3.102    21.741    7.167
```

So substantial improvement in speed. However, I had to first order the data before applying `someStatsFunction` (i.e. eliminating the need for an `if` statement at `customFunction`), to then run the function using the columns `response` and `time` in `myData`. Moreover, the raw output from

```
dt[order(time)][, (vNames) := as.list(someStatsFunction(response, time)), by = .(c1, c2)]
```

gives a table that does not return 1500 values (i.e. 30*50 combinations of `c1` and `c2`), but instead repeats combinations of `c1` and `c2` multiple times. Also, it does return the original `response` and `time` columns, though I only wanted the unique combinations of `c1` and `c2` bound to the stats from `someStatsFunction` (as in the output using `plyr` and/or `dplyr`), hence my final code

```
testDtb  <- dt[order(time)][, 
(vNames) := as.list(someStatsFunction(response, time)), 
by = .(c1, c2)][, 
head(.SD, 1), by = .(c1, c2)][, 
c('response', 'time') := NULL, ]
```

Is there anyway I can achieve the same output but in a much more simplified way?

Comment: Your example data is too tiny for the timing to matter. Maybe write it as dependent on #rows and #groups. Also, I guess you can simplify it (no reason to have two grouping vars c1 and c2)

Comment: Thanks Frank, I used this simple example with c1 and c2 because in my original data they are coordinates (lat long). I basically need to apply a complex function to  an environmental time series for each pair of coordinates. Does pasting the coordinates into one single grouping variable (for the purposes of the loop) and then splitting them back up in the output speed things up? Or would that just create additional unnecessary code?

Plus, I'm interested in learning whether a `data.table` alternative would speed things up considerably...

Comment: I don't expect that combining them would improve speed; I just meant it's extra complexity that we might not need to address the question... I think (but could be wrong) that only #groups matters (calculable as `uniqueN(setDT(mydata), by=c("c1", "c2"))` after data.table is loaded). Btw, if you want to know which grouped calculations are optimized, you could look at `?GForce`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the advice. The data.table concept is still very new to me, so I still don't quite know how to translate the examples above into the data.table framework. But I'll try to edit my post with a data.table example if I get one to work.

Comment: something like `setDT(myData)[order(time), someStatsFunction(response, time), by=.(c1, c2)]` will achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks so much **@chinsoon12**, your suggestion did the trick. I added a full comparison among methods below for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766144/faster-alternatives-to-ddply-and-group-by#comment90630831_51766144) provided by **@chinsoon12**, I was able to get my desired outcome:

```
library(plyr)  
library(dplyr)  
library(data.table)  
library(rbenchmark)  

someStatsFunction  <-  function (y, x) {
    x    <-  as.integer(x)
    mod  <-  coef(summary(lm(y ~ x)))
    data.frame(stats1  = 'something',
             intercept = mod[1],
             slope     = mod[2],
             meanx     = mean(x),
             statx     = sqrt(mean(abs(x)))/sd(y)^2)
}

customFunction  <-  function (data) {
    if (!all(sort(data$time) == data$time)) {
        stop('Column \'time\' is not ordered')
    }
    someStatsFunction(y = data$response, x = data$time)
}

myData  <-  data.frame(c1 = rep(rep(1:50, each = 30), 1095), c2 = rep(rep(1:30, 50), 1095), response = rnorm(30 * 50 * 1095), time = rep(seq(as.Date('1981-01-01'), as.Date('1983-12-31'), by = '1 day'), each = 50*30))

benchmark('testPlyr' = {
            testPlyr   <-  plyr::ddply(myData, .(c1, c2), customFunction)
        },
          'testDplyr' = {
            testDplyr  <-  myData %>% dplyr::group_by(c1,c2) %>% dplyr::do(customFunction(.))
        },
          'testDtb' = {
            testDtb  <-  setDT(myData)[order(time), someStatsFunction(response, time), by=.(c1, c2)]
        },
    replications = 3,
    columns      = c('test', 'replications', 'elapsed', 'relative', 'user.self', 'sys.self'))
```

Here's what I get for the benchmarking:

```
       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2 testDplyr            3  68.383    3.976    48.120   20.392
3   testDtb            3  17.201    1.000    17.232    0.008
1  testPlyr            3  57.938    3.368    49.676    8.304
```

In case you're interested in knowing whether the results are identical among the different methods, check:

```
all.equal(testDplyr, testDtb)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(testDplyr, testPlyr)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
dt <- as.data.table(myData)
rr <- dt[, .(
  lon = c1,
  lat = c2,
  name = 'something',
  mean = mean(response),
  sd = sd(response),
  statx = sqrt(abs(response)) / sd(response) ^ 2

), keyby = .(c1, c2)]
rr
#        c1 c2 lon lat      name        mean        sd     statx
#     1:  1  1   1   1 something  0.23841637 0.9384408 0.3253456
#     2:  1  1   1   1 something  0.23841637 0.9384408 0.2421654
#     3:  1  1   1   1 something  0.23841637 0.9384408 0.5321797
#     4:  1  1   1   1 something  0.23841637 0.9384408 0.4136648
#     5:  1  1   1   1 something  0.23841637 0.9384408 1.5863249
# ---                                                        
# 14996: 50 30  50  30 something -0.04082032 0.7156352 2.3970053
# 14997: 50 30  50  30 something -0.04082032 0.7156352 0.8375551
# 14998: 50 30  50  30 something -0.04082032 0.7156352 1.7826972
# 14999: 50 30  50  30 something -0.04082032 0.7156352 1.0293926
# 15000: 50 30  50  30 something -0.04082032 0.7156352 0.1376940
```

Comment: Hi @minem, thanks for the reply. This is a nice solution, and definitely faster than the dplyr or plyr approaches, and spits out the data in the exact same format, which is great. However, your example doesn't allow me to 'send' the entire data as an argument to `customFunction` -- this is necessary because this function performs checks of data quality (the 'if' statement) before applying the nested function `someStatsFunction`. In reality, I have a much more complex wrapper function (like `customFunction`) that depends on a series of nested functions to spit out the output data.frame.