# Predict number of rows in merge/join

Tags: memory, join, merge, pandas

In my code I use merge/join in numerous places. Recently I bumped on an join probably just making a Cartesian product  (probably only out of 5000 files to process). Since the code works on a 64 bit system/python, this join keeps running to fill all memory, blocking every process/user on this hardware node. Since no actual error occurs, it is very hard to debug as well.

Is there a easy way to test the validity of a join/merge, which i could use in an assert statement?

Thanks,

Luc

Comment: In my opinion the only way to do it is to understand the different join types ([this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra) gives the equivalent to SQL)

Comment: This is strange, I thought joins and merges were actually references rather that creating new data (in memory), what Wes means by ["cold"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8992714/1240268)?

Comment: merge/join creates a new dataframe, that the memory problem. I think of a test to check the content of the join fields. If the join columns do not match (compare two  set(index_col.values) of join columns) this might be used to decide to merge or just return an error...

Comment: You can create a function that takes names of 2 dataframes & join columns. then you can use loops to find out matching ones.