# Replace NA in a certain column with values from equal key from same column

Tags: r, data.table

I created a means column for a group based on a criterium C. Now I want those means to be filled out over the entire column, even when criterium C does not hold. So basically I want to replace `NA`'s with the mean value calculated for that group. You can see the grp, val and C colum in the next Data.table

```
    grp val C
 1:   1  NA 0
 2:   1  NA 0
 3:   1  42 1
 4:   1  42 1
 5:   2  16 1
 6:   2  16 1
 7:   2  NA 0
 8:   2  NA 0
 9:   3  32 1
10:   3  32 1
11:   3  32 1
12:   3  32 1
```

So I want to replace the `val` `NA`'s with the mean value in the same group.
Here is sample code of how I attempt to do it.
Basicly I extract another `data.table`, remove the `NA`'s and duplicates and then try to merge it with the original table.

```
x <- data.table(grp=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),val=c(NA,NA,42,42,16,16,NA,NA,32,32,32,32),C=c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1))
y <- x[!is.na(val),]
y <- y[!duplicated(y),]
setkey(x,grp)
setkey(y,grp)
x[y,val:=val,by=grp]
```

while this does not give any errors it leaves the original column `val` untouched. What am I doing wrong? what would be a better approach?

Comment: Do you just want `x[, val := mean(val, na.rm = TRUE), grp]`??

Comment: seems so... :o
I've been spending almost a days work on this...
thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest you spend some time on reading on how to use `data.table` appropriately. Start [**here**](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html)

Comment: If only you knew how much time I spend reading about data.table :(
I guess I was suffering from some tunnelvision... another mean calculation... :P

Perhaps as you are so experienced with it you could write some more documentation on different merges and other operations as I feel there is a significant lack of it. That link seems awesome at first sight though!

Comment: and don't forget to answer your question to remove it from unanswered list :) You might expect better documentation in 1.9.6.

Comment: Dplyr or plyr will help too.

Comment: @AlexBrown don't see how `dplyr` or especially `plyr` can provide a better solution than a simple line with `data.table` syntax

Comment: Data.table is no less core than dplyr, and significantly less so than plyr.  There's nothing g simple about data.table.

Comment: @AlexBrown First, this is a data.table question, Second, what is complicated about `x[, val := mean(val, na.rm = TRUE), grp]`? Why would the OP need to load some other package which will never achieve this performance/simplicity (neither don't have assignment by reference operator (`:=`)). Also, how `plyr` is more core than `data.table`?? Not to mention it has worse performance than even base R and it completely outdated.

Comment: Fair enough, I missed that it was a data.table question

Comment: Plyr is more core because it only uses standard R primitives.  Although it does have that performance issue you mention.

Comment: Although base has performance issues too and that never seemed to cause a problem.  Sorry, hobby horse of mine.

Comment: @DavidArenburg if you would post an answer I will accept it. Or should I post an answer myself? :P Of course it is questionable if this post should remain on StackOverflow because of the simplicity of the problem/solution..

Comment: Added an answer, as it seems like it could be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like this question is driving lots of "noise", so I'll add this as an answer.

So `data.table` has an "assignment by reference operator" which is `:=` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029944/when-should-i-use-the-operator-in-data-table) for more info and use cases/benchmarks).

This operator is assigning values to *all* the members of the particular group (although you can also use it without grouping by anything), similar to `mutate` function in `dplyr` or `ave` and `transform` in base R, *but* it does it *by reference* (which isn't too important for this question specifically, but is probably its greatest advantage over the equivalents in other packages/base R), i.e., it is updating the data set *itself* without creating copies while using the `<-` operator.

**To sum things up**, if you want to calculate some metric *per group* and assign it to *each* value in that particular group, use `:=`.

On other hand, if you want just the summary, use `=` instead (with combination with `list()` or just `.()`), or if you don't want to name the result of the aggregation, you *don't have to use anything at all* as in:

```
x[, .(val = mean(val, na.rm = TRUE)), grp]
```

Or

```
x[, list(val = mean(val, na.rm = TRUE)), grp]
```

Or just

```
x[, mean(val, na.rm = TRUE), grp] # will call the aggregated variable `V1` by default
```

The equivalents for this in `dplyr` would be `summarise` and in base R it would be `aggregate` or sometimes `tapply`.

---

That being said, in your specific case you would use the `:=` operator in order to assign the `mean` value *per* group to *each* value in that particular group as in:

```
x[, val := mean(val, na.rm = TRUE), grp]
```

Answer (score 1):

For imputing the NA's with group mean, `data.table` and `dplyr` would work well (data.table vs dplyr is a separate discussion). Refer @ David Arenburg's comment for `data.table` method code for replacing NA with mean.

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate(val= replace(val, is.na(val), mean(val, na.rm=TRUE))) # ifelse can also be tried instead of replace
```

Less elegant way is through a custom function combined with ddply:

```
library(plyr)
# function to replace NA with mean for that group
impute.mean <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))

df <- ddply(df, ~ grp, transform, val = impute.mean(val))
```

Comment: Why *the best* way is using `ddply`? what wrong with just the `data.table` syntax? he is already using? And if you already going with the `plyr` path, why do you need to create a new function, what's wrong with just `ddply(x, ~ grp, transform, val = mean(val, na.rm = TRUE))`?

Comment: I realized my mistake, thanks David. I have now edited the answer and up voted your comments containing the codes.