# line by line debugging in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to debug the code line by line in R studio environment ??

I know there are breakpoints, Next, continue etc to debug. But I am looking for a line by line debug option like the one in Visual Studio.

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't the Next option do what you are expecting, i.,e step through the code? If not, what exactly do you mean by line by line debugging?

Comment: @shark1608 This actually works but I was looking for something like "debug" option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `debug` package is probably what you want. If you are debugging via this package an extra window opens in which your code is displayed and then you can debug line by line in combination with RStudio.

EDIT:

See below example code for how to debug with the `debug` package:

```
install.packages("debug")
library(debug)

fun <- function(x) {
  y <- x + 1
  z <- y + 1
  return(z)
}

mtrace(fun)
fun(2)
```

Comment: Yes, debug is what I wanted. I went through the tutorial. Thank you :-) But, when I install the debug package, its actually not prompting any window to debug. Is there something wrong with my machine or software ?

Comment: I added a small example to my earlier post. Running the above code should generate an extra window.

Comment: @User33 Why I cannot install this package? Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘debug’ is not available for this version of R

Comment: @Hermi I think the package is no longer maintained. Debugging in R Studio is now further developed than at the time of my answer (5 years ago). Hence, using the debugging tools that are described in the answer by Stefan and are available in R Studio https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio seems to be a good alternative.

Answer (score 6):

For R-Studio newbies like me that are used to other IDEs:

a) Set a break point by clicking on the border or pressing `Shift+F9` (=>red break point dot is shown)

b) As equivalent to "Debug" in other IDEs:

- Click `source` or
- Press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` or
- Activate `source on save` and save

c) Have a look at the `Console` view. There are common debug options:

- Execute Next Line `F10`
- Step Into Function `Shift+F4`
- Finish function `Shift+F6`
- Continue `Shift+F5`
- Stop Debugging `Shift+F8`

(Unfortunately I did not find a way to adapt the key shortcuts for those options. They are not listed under Tools=>Modify Keyboard shortcuts.)

[image]

d) There does not seem to be a "hover over expression" feature while debugging. You can have a look at the `Environment` view to see the value of a variable and use the Console to evaluate expressions while debugging.

If you want to run the script without debugging and without clearing the break points, select all lines `Ctrl+A` and use the Run button. (Seems to be complicated to me.... I would expect an extra run button or key shortcut for that but could not find one.)

If there is no selection, the **Run button only executes the current line**. You can press that button several times to step through the code and see the corresponding console output (=pseudo debugging).

Also see documentation at

- https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484448-Editing-and-Executing-Code
- https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio

and related questions:

- [Disable all breakpoints in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959164/disable-all-breakpoints-in-rstudio)
- [Debugging a function in a different source file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516192/debugging-a-function-in-a-different-source-file-in-r)
- [Rstudio debug - missing step into button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395122/rstudio-debug-missing-step-into-button)
- https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202156378-how-do-i-clear-the-console-

Comment: I suppose this answer is better than the accepted one.

Comment: Is there any way to give specific condition to the debugged line?