# The debug package does not open a separate window?

Tags: r

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358659/line-by-line-debugging-in-r-studio) I had asked about debugging and the suggestion was to use **debug** package. It was told that debug package would prompt me a new window for an interactive debugging session but isn't doing it.

Can somebody give me an example?
I am using Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that debug helps us to debug a function separately. The syntax follows
debug(fun, text = "", condition = NULL). So one can debug their functions interactively.