# Rstudio debug - missing step into button

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I'm an R newbie, working with Rstudio.
when I create a new project on **my machine**, 
including multiple files, and try to debug via the consul,
I do not see the "step into" and "execute reminder" buttons in the pane,
but only the "next", "continue" and "stop" buttons.

this is strange, as in other machines I was able to install Rstudio and avoid this issue.I have tried to re-install Rstudio on my machine, but the issue persist. 
thanks, 
Shay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what version of R you have. I believe that the Step Into and Execute Remainder features were introduced in R 3.1 so you may be running a version earlier than that.