# Disable all breakpoints in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

Is there a a way to disable all breakpoints in RStudio? I have looked at the RStudio documentation as well as done google searches but couldn't find a way.

Comment: RStudio doesn't have a "disabled" state for breakpoints. You can clear (remove) all the breakpoints via Debug -> Clear All Breakpoints.

Answer (score 5):

I was curious too, especially wanted to have an overview of breakpoints.

I ran `grep` in my project folder and this is what I found:

At first, with RStudio opened, the breakpoints don't show up, they're probably somewhere in memory:

```
$ grep -inIEr "breakpoint" .
./.Rproj.user/1C48145B/pcs/debug-breakpoints.pper:2:    "debugBreakpointsState" : {
./.Rproj.user/1C48145B/pcs/debug-breakpoints.pper:3:        "breakpoints" : [
grep: ./.Rproj.user/1C48145B/sources/s-8EAA4F36/lock_file: Device or resource busy
```

Then when we close RStudio, it seems they're written to a file called `debug-breakpoints.pper`

```
$ grep -inIEr "breakpoint" .
./.Rproj.user/1C48145B/pcs/debug-breakpoints.pper:2:    "debugBreakpointsState" : {
./.Rproj.user/1C48145B/pcs/debug-breakpoints.pper:3:        "breakpoints" : [
./.Rproj.user/1C48145B/pcs/debug-breakpoints.pper:10:                "is_package_breakpoint" : false,
./.Rproj.user/1C48145B/pcs/debug-breakpoints.pper:25:                "is_package_breakpoint" : false,
./.Rproj.user/1C48145B/pcs/find-in-files.pper:7:        "query" : "breakpoint",
```

The file can be found at `./.Rproj.user/1C4***5B/pcs/debug-breakpoints.pper` and looks like this:

```
{
    "debugBreakpointsState" : {
        "breakpoints" : [
            {
                "editor_line_number" : 4,
                "editor_state" : 1,
                "function_name" : "toplevel",
                "function_steps" : "",
                "id" : 2,
                "is_package_breakpoint" : false,
                "is_pending_debug_completion" : false,
                "line_number" : 4,
                "needs_updated_steps" : false,
                "package_name" : "",
                "path" : "C:/Users/path/to/project/analysis_tab.R",
                "state" : 1,
                "type" : 1
            },
            {
                "editor_line_number" : 193,
                "editor_state" : 1,
                "function_name" : "toplevel",
                "function_steps" : "",
                "id" : 3,
                "is_package_breakpoint" : false,
                "is_pending_debug_completion" : false,
                "line_number" : 193,
                "needs_updated_steps" : false,
                "package_name" : "",
                "path" : "C:/Users/path/to/project/analysis_tab.R",
                "state" : 1,
                "type" : 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Manually editing this file when RStudio is closed lets us manage our breakpoints. (With RStudio opened, changes made to this file would eventually be overwritten).

Answer (score 4):

It's right there under the Debug menu:
[image]

Default keyboard shortcut (on my system): Ctrl+Shift+F9

Comment: Clear All Breakpoints doesn't work for me.