# Convert integer to base/iterate through all possibilities

Tags: r

I need to iterate through all possible realisations of a vector of length `n`, each element being a number from 1 to `g`. There are `g^n` of these; `g` is typically 3, while `n` will be as large as I can reasonably get R to handle. On each realisation I'll calculate something `f(z)` (where `z` is the realisation) and add it to a running total (normalising constant of a distribution, if you want to know).

One example with `n=10` would be `c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2)`.

I could do this with say some sort of `expand.grid` cleverness and loop through each row, **but is it possible to go through each realisation without holding them all simultaneously in memory?**

With the `expand.grid` (or similar) method where I would generate say a (`g^n`) * `n` matrix of `z` possibilities, I would have to store them all in memory at once.

One option to avoid this is to iterate through all integers from `0` to `g^n - 1`; convert this to a number in base `g` (it will have `n` characters from 0 to `g-1`); and then add one to get a realisation of `z`. However, I couldn't find a convenient (fast?) function to convert from an integer to a given base unless that base happened to be 2, 6, or 8.

So, does anyone know how I may convert an integer to a `z`, or alternatively how I may conveniently construct a loop over all possible `z` without having to store them all simultaneously at once?

Comment: You might find something helpful [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143323/pythons-xrange-alternative-for-r-or-how-to-loop-over-large-dataset-lazilly)

Comment: A more verbose/documented form of my answer (motivated/improved by @alexis_laz, in fact) is in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/r2evans/e5531cbab8cf421d14ed).

Comment: The `trotter` package uses pseudo-vectors for combinations: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trotter/index.html

Comment: Have you tried `transpose()` in package `purrr`?

Comment: Thanks guys, will check it out (the gist, alexis_laz' answer, and trotter). I do not see how `transpose()` can answer this question? ("it turns a pair of lists into a list of pairs" - I don't have or need pairs, and if this were extended to say `g-` or `n-`tuples I'd still have to store them all at once in order to iterate, which I'm trying to avoid.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of looping through all possibilities - not sure how fast it would be, but it certainly avoids setting up a large array

```
n <- 4
g <- 3
a <- rep(1,n) #initialise to a vector of 1s
while(max(a) < g + 1){
  cat(a,"\n") #insert your own function here
  a[1] <- a[1] + 1 #increment first element
  for(i in 2:n){ #this loop 'carries forward'
    if(a[i-1] > g){
      a[i-1] <- 1
      a[i] <- a[i] + 1
    }
  }
}
```