# XDF Files: outputting all possible combinations

Tags: r, microsoft-r

In base-R, if you have a data frame and want to output all possible combinations of variables, you can use `expand.grid()`

I was looking for something similar in Microsoft R/RevoscaleR when dealing with XDF files which are too large to be in memory.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It's something that would be good to get an answer for this topic but why not make a small example so demonstration code would be more likely to appear and be useful for future searches? It would also be good to provide information about the number of unique items in such a use case.

Comment: I couldn't find any function similar to expand.grid that does this by looking at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/r-reference/revoscaler/revoscaler), perhaps check `rxDataStep`.  Another option is to convert it to data.frame with one of the Rx functions but if memory is a constraint it would not be viable

Comment: There is no built-in function for this, and I suspect writing one would be nontrivial.

Comment: I guess this is related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830697/expand-grid-in-r-vector-is-too-large-error). The answer is: don't do this. Even if you could create such a combinatorial object, actually computing anything with it will take a ridiculously long time. You need to find a smarter way of checking your model.

Comment: But, I really, really want to do this. :)

Comment: No, you really, really don't. More hardware is not an excuse to use an O(p^N) approach.

Comment: I know. I now have to come up with a more clever solution.