# conditionally sample in R

Tags: r, function, combinations, sample

I've found [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143323/pythons-xrange-alternative-for-r-or-how-to-loop-over-large-dataset-lazilly/36144255#36144255) in another post that sequentially outputs combinations of vectors when called. It is essentially a work around to `expand.grid` when there are large numbers of vectors with many elements.

Here is the function:

```
lazyExpandGrid <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  argnames <- names(dots)
  if (is.null(argnames)) argnames <- paste0('Var', seq_along(dots))
  sizes <- lengths(dots)
  indices <- cumprod(c(1L, sizes))
  maxcount <- indices[ length(indices) ]
  i <- 0
  function(index) {
    i <<- if (missing(index)) (i + 1L) else index
    if (length(i) > 1L) return(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(i, sys.function(0))))
    if (i > maxcount || i < 1L) return(FALSE)
    setNames(Map(`[[`, dots, (i - 1L) %% indices[-1L] %/% indices[-length(indices)] + 1L  ),
             argnames)
  }
}
```

Here are some example calls:

```
set.seed(42)
nxt <- lazyExpandGrid(a=1:1e2, b=1:1e2, c=1:1e2, d=1:1e2, e=1:1e2, f=1:1e2)
as.data.frame(nxt()) # prints the 1st possible combination
nxt(sample(1e2^6, size=7)) # prints 7 sampled rows from the sample space
```

What I cannot figure out is how to conditionally sample using `lazyExpandGrid2`. I would like to exclude samples if they have certain numbers of elements.

For example say i have these vectors for which I want to create unique combinations of: `a=0:3, b=0:4, c=0:5`. I could create samples using: `nxt(sample(50, size=50, replace = F))`.

But lets say I am not interested in samples where there are two 0s. How could I exclude these samples? I've tried things like: `nxt(sample(which(!(sum(as.data.frame(nxt()) == 0)==2)), size=50, replace = F))`.

I just don't understand how to reference the sampled row in `sample()` to be able to exclude it if it doesn't meet a certain criteria.

Comment: You would have to pre-compute the valid indices not matching your exclusion criterion. Alternatively, you could drop samples that don't fit after the call to `nxt`.

Comment: So the only way to do it would be pre-compute or something like this: nxt <- lazyExpandGrid(a=0:3, b=0:4, c=0:5)
x <-  as.data.frame(nxt())
for (i in 1:119){
  y <- as.data.frame(nxt())
  if(!(sum(y == 0)==2)){x <- rbind(x,y)}
  
}

x

Comment: The second method seems inefficient because I do not necessarily need all of the possible combinations meeting the criteria, and with many vectors with many elements the possible combinations would get enormous. Is there a way to combine sample with the above code? It would need to sample without replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to drop rows that don't meet a condition, I don't think you need to worry about sampling without replacement as passing the same value to`nxt` should generate an identical row, which would still be dropped. It might work, then, to make a wrapper for the function as you've defined it above that just doesn't include a `nxt`-generated row if it doesn't meet the condition you're after. Here, the row is dropped if the number of zeroes is equal to 2:

```
set.seed(0123)

nxt <- lazyExpandGrid(a = 0:3, b = 0:4, c = 0:5)

nxtDrop <- function(samp, n_row){
  t(sapply(1:n_row, function(x) {
    y = nxt(sample(samp, 1))
    while (length(grep(0, y)) == 2) {
      y = nxt(sample(samp, 1))
    }
    return(y)
  }))
}

> nxtDrop(120, 10)
      a b c
 [1,] 2 3 1
 [2,] 2 3 4
 [3,] 1 2 2
 [4,] 1 1 5
 [5,] 0 3 5
 [6,] 1 1 0
 [7,] 3 0 3
 [8,] 3 1 5
 [9,] 2 1 3
[10,] 2 3 2
```