# Getting memory error on expand.grid() in R

Tags: r, rstudio, data-science

I am running into memory problems and need help to fix it .I cannot publish the exact code or results here due to confidentiality issues of my company. However, I have used dummy references as below

There are 2 data frames as below

```
data frame A looks like
id  x_1  x_2   x_3  x_4
1  data   data  data data
2  data   data  data data
3  data   data  data data

data frame B looks like
id_1  x_1  x_2   x_3  x_4
1    data   data  data data
2    data   data  data data
3    data   data  data data
```

The hope was to get a combination result of the first columns of A and B as

```
id  id_1
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    1
2    2
2    3
3    1
3    2
3    3
```

Thus, used expand.grid as :

```
myLoadedData1 <- expand.grid(A$id,B$id)
```

The expand.grid was working fine when both A and B data frames had 8000 records each.

Due to scalability that cannot be avoided, the records have now increased to 50000 in both data frames. Now we see the below issue

```
 myLoadedData1 <- expand.grid(A$id,B$id)  
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.1 Gb
```

Please help the project is sort of stuck now and need ideas to move past this .
Please see my session info below

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.8.4        dplyr_0.7.7       odbc_1.1.6        data.table_1.11.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17     assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2         DBI_1.0.0        magrittr_1.5     pillar_1.2.3     rlang_0.2.1      blob_1.1.1      
 [9] bindrcpp_0.2.2   tools_3.5.1      bit64_0.9-7      glue_1.2.0       purrr_0.2.5      bit_1.1-14       hms_0.4.2        yaml_2.1.19     
[17] compiler_3.5.1   pkgconfig_2.0.1  tidyselect_0.2.4 bindr_0.1.1      tibble_1.4.2
```

Comment: If all you are doing is two numeric columns, can you use an external looping mechanism, either two `for` loops or two nested `lapply(1:8000, function(i) lapply(1:9000, function(j) { ...yourcodehere...}))`? (The only other option would be to use an analogy of a python's lazy generators. A prev answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36144255/3358272, with a documented gist https://gist.github.com/r2evans/e5531cbab8cf421d14ed.)

Comment: @r2evans: Thank you for helping, I tried the lapply approach but it failed stating maximum memory reached. I am now trying the for loop approach and will keep you posted of the results.