# How to compute the size of the allocated memory for a general type

Tags: r

I need to work with some databases read with `read.table` from csv (comma separated values ),  and I wish to know how to compute the size of the allocated memory for each type of variable.

How to do it ?

edit -- in other words : how much memory R allocs for a general data frame read from a `.csv` file ?

Comment: [**This post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) may be useful to check the memory of allocated objects in an R session. In particular Tony Breyal's modification of Dirk's function.

Comment: I do not see there how to compute on paper the size of a table that has integers and categorical variables.

Comment: Sorry, never heard of someone wanting to do that before. I should have misread your question.

Comment: My question is : if I look with the eye to a cvs file, how can I compute on paper how much memory R allocs ?

Comment: for integer values, I think the answer of David answers correctly.

Comment: Have you read `?Memory`? It maybe a nice place to start.

Comment: Computing on paper is usually not as good an idea as actually running `object.size`. What if your operating system, version of R, or specifics of your variable are different?

Comment: Yes. As I re/commented, I wanted to say that I wanted to understand it in general, algorithmically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the amount of memory allocated to an object with `object.size`. For example:

```
x = 1:1000
object.size(x)
# 4040 bytes
```

[This script](http://heuristically.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/r-memory-usage-statistics-variable/) might also be helpful- it lets you view or graph the amount of memory used by all of your current objects.

In answer to your question of why `object.size(4)` is 48 bytes, the reason is that there is some overhead in each numeric vector. (In `R`, the number `4` is not just an integer as in other languages- it is a numeric vector of length 1). But that doesn't hurt performance, because the overhead does not increase with the size of the vector. If you try:

```
> object.size(1:100000) / 100000
4.0004 bytes
```

This shows you that each integer itself requires only 4 bytes (as you expect).

Thus, summary:

- For a numeric vector of length `n`, the size in bytes is typically `40 + 8 * floor(n / 2)`. However, on my version of R and OS there is a single slight discontinuity, where it jumps to 168 bytes faster than you would expect (see plot below). Beyond that, the linear relationship holds, even up to a vector of length 10000000.

  ```
  plot(sapply(1:50, function(n) object.size(1:n)))
  ```

[image]

- For a categorical variable, you can see a very similar linear trend, though with a bit more overhead (see below). Outside of a few slight discontinuities, the relationship is quite close to `400 + 60 * n`.

  ```
  plot(sapply(1:100, function(n) object.size(factor(1:n))))
  ```

[image]

Comment: @alinsoar: Is your question "why does a numeric vector of length 1 take up 48 bytes"?

Comment: @alinsoar: my latest edit explains why it's 48 bytes. Is there some other reason you find it surprising?

Comment: Yes. You can confirm this with `plot(sapply(1:100000, function(n) object.size(1:n)))`, which shows a linear plot.

Comment: @alinsoar: I show how to do the computation for factor variables in my answer. For reasons I explain in my comment above, it is still a better idea to do `object.size` on your own variables rather than compute on paper.

Comment: @alinsoar: In any case, you should try both of my `plot` lines of code on your own machine to make sure this matches your OS and version of R.

Comment: -- perfect. I did not think to make a plot of memo allocation. great.