# Why an empty matrix is 208 bytes?

Tags: r

In his book, Hadley Wickam explains why an empty vector is 40 bytes in the section [memory](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html). But what about a matrix? A matrix also has, at least, two integers in its attributes to store the number of columns and the number of rows. But it is not sufficient to explain why an empty matrix is 208 bytes. I was expecting something like 48 bytes.

```
> object.size(matrix())
208 bytes
```

Comment: That's not an empty matrix.

Comment: `object.size(matrix(, nrow = 0, ncol = 0))` gives 200 bytes.

Comment: See [Same memory usage of matrix with different size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465592/same-memory-usage-of-matrix-with-different-size): "a matrix needs an extra 160 bytes of storage compared to a vector. Why 160 bytes? It's because a matrix has an `dim` attribute containing two integers, and attributes are stored in a `pairlist`". `object.size(pairlist(dims = c(1L, 1L)))`; `160 bytes`