# R large data frame with factors won't shrink when subset

Tags: r, character, subset, r-factor

I have a large-ish data frame (100k Row x 50 Col) with several factor variables.  I want a small subset (like 100 rows) to do some prototyping with.  The problem is when I type :

```
train <- train[1:100,]
```

the size shrinks (using `dim()`) but it still appears to store all the factors from the original data frame (I'm measuring memory size using `lsos()` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session)).

Is there a way to get around this?  So far the only way I've found is to turn the factor variables to character strings then subset, then convert to factors again.  I feel like there has to be a better way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `droplevels` function to get rid of the levels that are not in the new data.frame, see `?droplevels` for more info.

Example:

```
> DF <- data.frame(num=1:15, letter=rep(letters[1:5], each=3),random=rnorm(15))
> levels(DF[, 2]) # all levels
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
> 
> DF2 <- DF[1:10, ] # subseting
> levels(DF2[, 2]) # all levels again
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
> DF2[, 2] <- droplevels(DF2[, 2])
> levels(DF2[, 2]) # only the levels contained in DF2
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Comment: +1, great, I didn't know about `droplevels`.