# Appending to large data.frame and hitting memory limit

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to append a month's worth of data (200k) rows to a data.frame that is already 16m rows, and am hitting the R memory limit on my system:

```
d = rbind(d, n)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 60.8 Mb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rbind(deparse.level, ...) :
  Reached total allocation of 8072Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

`memory.size` and `memory.max` report 2187.88 and 8072 respectively, so I think i'm using all my 8GB system memory.  Using an object memory reporting function detailed by [JD Long in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session), I get the following  report:

```
            Type          Size     Rows Columns
d     data.table 2,231,877,576 15941535      26
files  character           912       13      NA
i        numeric            48        1      NA
n     data.frame    28,176,000   213116      26
```

Is there another way to append to a data.frame that does not entail the apparent object duplication that seems to be taking place and eating up memory?  I am keen to avoid appending to csv files because I'm working with .RData saved objects for quicker data reading-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `data.table` objects you should use `rbindlist` to avoid making unnecessary copies of your `data.table`. This should work...

```
d = rbindlist(d, n)
```