# Get list of available data frames

Tags: r, shiny

How do I get vector of data frame names available in current environment? I've tried:

```
sapply(ls(), is.data.frame)
```

But this fails because `ls` returns vector of strings. I'm planning to use this list as a input for dynamic selection in Shiny app.

Comment: I use a modified `lsos()` function based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `eapply` to loop through the objects in an environment:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- mtcars
eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame)
$x
[1] FALSE

$y
[1] TRUE

names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame))))
[1] "y"
```

Comment: This is nice. Careful with that last line though, it will only work properly in the global environment since `eapply()` is explicitly targeting `.GlobalEnv` whereas `ls()` isn't (won't work right in a function). Could do something like: `names(Filter(isTRUE, eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.data.frame)))` then there's no need for `ls()` or `unlist()`.

Comment: @MadScone Yes, I was a little lax with the last line. I have put an alternative in now.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're asking for the actual names of these data frames rather than the data frames themselves? You can do:

```
l <- ls()
l[sapply(l, function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)))]
```

`get()` will return the value of an object given a character name.

---

Tidier way of doing basically the same thing:

```
Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)), ls())
```

Answer (score 5):

You need `get`, try this:

```
x <- sapply(sapply(ls(), get), is.data.frame)
names(x)[(x==TRUE)]
```

Comment: I think `sapply(ls(), get)` is the same as `mget(ls())`?

Answer (score 3):

I use a modified `lsos()` function based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session)

```
library(devtools)
source_url("https://raw.github.com/rsaporta/pubR/gitbranch/memoryFunctions.R")

## only show data.frames of at least ~1KB
lsos(t="data.frame")

## show data.frames of any size
lsos(t="data.frame", b=1)

### OUTPUT

           KB       Type Rows Columns
anotherDF   5 data.frame   50       4
df        0.8 data.frame    5       2
```