# How to use lm function for large number of attributes

Tags: r, linear-regression

i have a dataset with 1 label attribute and 784 pixel attributes  with 42000 rows like below

```
label  pixel0  pixel1  pixel2 ...........  pixel783  
0        1     0         0                   16
.  
.  
1        2      15       1                    0
```

Now i want to perform regression on it and so i use `lm` function

```
lm(label~pixel0+pixel1+pixel2..........+pixel784,data=df )
```

but to write pixel0 to pixel 784 is , according to me foolishness.
Is there a way to avoid manually writing the above exp or i have to do so?

Comment: `label ~ .`. And this is the mnist handwritten digits, so you probably don't want to be using `lm`

Comment: it's not working as it shows Error: cannot allocate vector of size 251.5 Mb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
  Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)

Comment: How much memory does your computer have? 1.5 GB? That error shows up because you are running out or memory not because of an error in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use . as described in the help page for `formula`. The . stands for `"all columns not otherwise in the formula"`.

```
lm(label ~ ., data = df)
```

Alternatively, construct the formula manually with paste. This example is from the `as.formula()` help page:

```
xnam <- paste("x", 1:784, sep="")
(fmla <- as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(xnam, collapse= "+"))))
```

You can then insert this object into regression function:

```
lm(fmla, data = df)
```

Comment: though the command is right but there seems to be memory problem as always i am getting the error as  Error: cannot allocate vector of size 251.5 Mb In addition: Warning messages: 1: In lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :

Comment: as Jake mentioned you are running out of memory.why don't you try `lm.fit` instead of `lm` to narrow down the problem? `lm.fit` just does more-or-less "raw" linear model fitting via the `QR decomposition` If you also get memory problems with lm.fit check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session