# R / devtools / roxygen2 : difficulty creating package

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen2

I'm trying to turn this function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) into an R package.  I'm following the directions found [here](http://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/).

Here are the steps I take:

1) Load required library

```
library(devtools)
```

2) Go to a new location

```
setwd('C:\\myRpkgs\\')
```

3) Create skeleton

```
create('conveniencePkg')
```

4) Copy function to file and save in `'C:\\myRpkgs\\conveniencePkg\\R\\lsos.R'`

5) Run document function

```
setwd("./conveniencePkg")
document()
```

6) Install package

```
setwd("..")
install("conveniencePkg")
```

7) Load library

```
library(conveniencePkg)
```

8) try to use lsos function

```
>lsos()
Error in is.na(obj.dim)[, 1] : subscript out of bounds
```

Result is the following error:

```
> traceback()
2: .ls.objects(..., order.by = "Size", decreasing = TRUE, head = TRUE, 
       n = n)
1: conveniencePkg::lsos()
```

The function runs fine if I put it into an R file and just use the `source()` function.  Anything seem incorrect in the above steps?

Comment: The error message is pretty simple. Why don't you just `debug()` the function `.ls.objects` (which I presume is from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1358003/324364)) and see exactly why `obj.dim` doesn't have the right dimensions? Then you'd actually know what went wrong, which seems like the first step to solving it.

Comment: it doesn't work because there are no objects in the workspace when you load the package into a clean r session. it works when you source it because you are also creating the lsos object so obj.dim has the correct dimensions to return [, 1] without error

Comment: @rawr : You're right.  Didn't realize package objects are treated differently than source() generated objects.  Thanks for pointing that out.