# Get the amount of RAM that an environment uses in R

Tags: r, ram

Apparently `object.size` does not work here:

```
> e = new.env()
> e$a = 1:10000
> e$b = 1:10000
> object.size(e)
56 bytes
> e$c = 1:10000
> object.size(e)
56 bytes
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tricks to manage the available memory in an R session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `object_size` function from [pryr](http://cran.r-project.org/package=pryr) package:

```
> library(pryr)
> e = new.env()
> e$a = 1:10000
> e$b = 1:10000
> object.size(e)
28 bytes
> object_size(e)
80.3 kB
> e$c = 1:10000
> object.size(e)
28 bytes
> object_size(e)
120 kB
```

See also Hadley's doc about memory in R: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R solution:

```
sum(sapply(e, object.size))
```