# Region polygons not displaying in ggplot2 Choropleth map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'm trying to do a very basic map plot with ggplot2. I can't find why the colored polygons would not display. It seems that my code is no different from what I can find on the many tutorials and the questions already answered on this website. I think it could come from the way I prepare the data (see 100% reproducible example below).

```
library(maptools)
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)
con <- url("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/R/GHA_adm1.RData")
print(load(con))
close(con)

ghaDF<-as.data.frame(gadm)
ghaDF$prod <- c(12, 26, 12,22,0,11,4,5,4,4) # add values for the regions to be colored with
gadm@data$id = rownames(gadm@data) #create an id in the shapefile data
ghaMap <- fortify(gadm, region="id")
colnames(ghaDF[5])<-"id"
ghaMap <- merge(ghaMap, ghaDF)

m0 <- ggplot(data=ghaMap)
m1 <- m0 + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, fill = prod, group=group)) 
         + scale_fill_gradient(low = "light green", high = "dark green")
m2 <- m1 + geom_path(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),color='gray')  
         + coord_equal()
m2
```

[image: ghana map without region polygons]

On the image above (the output of `m2`), the regions should be colored according to the `ghaMap$prod` variable. Any suggestions?

(R version 3.0.2 - Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit))

Comment: +1 for a very reproducible question. It's unusual to not have to go hunting for shapefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is very simple. Change

```
colnames(ghaDF[5])<-"id"
```

to

```
colnames(ghaDF)[5]<-"id"
```

and your code produces the map you want.

The first line above extracts column 5 of `ghaDF` as a data frame with 1 column, sets that column name to `"id"`, and discards it when the call to `colnames(...)` completes. *It does not affect the original data frame at all.*

The second line extracts the column names of `ghaDF` as a character vector, and sets the 5th element of that vector to `"id"`, which in effect changes the name of column 5 of `ghaDF`.

Having said all this, your workflow is a bit tortured. For one thing you are merging all the columns of `gadm@data` into `ghaMap`, which is unnecessary and extremely inefficient. The code below produces the same map:

```
load(url("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/R/GHA_adm1.RData"))
ghaMap <- fortify(gadm)
ghaDF  <- data.frame(id=rownames(gadm@data),
                     prod=c(12,26,12,22,0,11,4,5,4,4))
ghaMap <- merge(ghaMap,ghaDF)
ggplot(ghaMap, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=prod))+
  geom_path(color="gray")+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "light green", high = "dark green")+
  coord_map()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your data seems fine. Here's a solution with `geom_map` (and, colorbrewer colors :-):

```
devtools::source_gist("https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/33baa3a79c5cfef0f6df")
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=ghaMap, map=ghaMap,
                    aes(map_id=id, group=group,
                        x=long, y=lat, fill=prod))
gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient(low="#99d8c9", high="#00441b")
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + theme_map() + theme(legend.position="right")
gg
```

[image: img]

You can omit the `devtools…` and `theme_map()` without impacting the solution.

**EDIT** Using simplified polygons

```
library(maptools)
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)

# get the shapefile
download.file("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/shp/GHA_adm.zip", "GHA_adm.zip")
unzip("GHA_adm.zip", exdir="GHA_adm")

# simplify it
setwd("GHA_adm")
system("ogr2ogr -simplify 0.001 simple1.shp GHA_adm1.shp") # simplify (500K -> 80K)
setwd("..")

# read it in
gadm <- readOGR("GHA_adm", "simple1")

# convert it
gadm_map <- fortify(gadm, region="NAME_1")

# make the values we want to fill with
# you can use "ID_1" but folks I've seen generally like using names. works either way
prod <- data.frame(id=gadm$NAME_1, value=c(12, 26, 12, 22, 0, 11, 4, 5, 4, 4), stringsAs=FALSE)

# merge the data together
gadm_map <- merge(gadm_map, prod, all.x=TRUE) # add it right into the fortified data frame

# plot it
devtools::source_gist("https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/33baa3a79c5cfef0f6df")
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=gadm_map, map=gadm_map,
                    aes(map_id=id, group=group,
                        x=long, y=lat, fill=value))
gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient(low="#99d8c9", high="#00441b")
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + theme_map() + theme(legend.position="right")
gg
```

(same map as above with slightly less edge detail)

[image]

Using `lsos` ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session)):

```
lsos()

##                               Type   Size Rows Columns
## gadm_map                data.frame 275256 5167       9
## gadm      SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 168296   10       9
## gg                              gg  34792    9      NA
## prod                    data.frame   2136   10       3
```

vs the same from the OP:

```
##                               Type    Size  Rows Columns
## ghaMap                  data.frame 3689120 31735      18
## gadm      SpatialPolygonsDataFrame  589424    10      11
## gg                              gg   34792     9      NA
## ghaDF                   data.frame    5088    10      12
## con                            url     552     1      NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it. I just updated my R version and all my packages. 

I noticed that the gg plot outputs size is around 31Mb. When I type `memory.size()`, I get  `[1] 24.1` returned. I am trying to find if this is linked.

Comment: I did notice it's a huge shapefile spatial data frame. Can you link to the source shapefile d/l? I can simplify the shapefiles for you pretty quickly.

Comment: The shapefile can be obtained [here](http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2/shp/GHA_adm.zip). It is the `GHA_adm1`.

Comment: Many thanks @hrbrmstr for the time you have spent on this solution. The simplified polygons solution is actually working for me. But I guess it is due to the alternative way you input the values to fill with. But it is very good to know how to simplify the shapefiles. thks.