# Parallel processing in R and memory management

Tags: r, memory-leaks, parallel-processing, mcmc

I have implemented the Metropolis-Hasting algorithm for one my projects and I use that along with "snowfall" package to build different chains of MCMC on different cores.
But now, what happens is, as soon as I begin to run my code for example for 30,000 times, each core takes up a 130MB chunk of the RAM and in each iteration they each take 300KB more. So pretty soon they all use all of my RAM and my code stops working. I never add any row dynamically to my matrices and I remove unnecessary variables at the end of each iteration.

So what I am suspicious about, is those variables that I overwrite them in each iteration (because basically there is nothing else left) but I have not seen or read anywhere that overwriting a variable may add to the total memory used by R. Here is a example of my code:

```
mcmc.func<-function(...){    
 nitr<-30000
 out <- matrix(NA, nitr, 6) # output which contains all the parameters posterior
 j<-1

 for (i in 1:nitr) {

  repeat {
    news <- t(as.matrix(mvrnorm(n = 1, (means), (diag(x = sd, 6, 6) ^ 2)*scale)))       }
    if(check.sample(news)){break;}#check the constrains 
         }

  ... doing some stuff.... (finding prior (pratio) and liklihood (cost))

  if (runif(1, 0, 1) < ((exp( - cost_c) / exp( - oldCost)) * pratio)) {

  out[j,]<-c(news, cost_c) # filling up my matrix 

 ... other stuff ...

 }

 j<-j+1

 }
}#end of the function
```

and here is the snowfall code:

```
library(snowfall)
sfInit(cpus = 15, parallel = TRUE,type="SOCK") #initiating the cluster

sfSource("C:/Users/hamzed/Dropbox/Var_setup.R") # shared variables
sfSource("C:/Users/hamzed/Dropbox/Utility.r") # all functions I used
sfSource("C:/Users/hamzed/Dropbox/Metropolis_func.R") # The Metriplos algorithm

sfExportAll() # exports all global variables from the master to all slaves

wrapper<-function(c){
## running MCMC for different files on different cores
return( mcmc.func(c))
}


outputNB<-sfClusterApplyLB(c(1:3,5,7:8),wrapper)
sfCat()
sfStop() ## stop cluster
```

Anybody any idea ?

Comment: I don't see any snowfall code there.

Comment: I just put my main function, but I just edit the code and put the snowfall too.

Comment: I found one more clue. I checked the RAM usage of my main function (mcmc.func) using Dirk tips (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) and there was absolutely no change !!! So to me it means there is something wrong with how snowfall manages the RAM. Any idea what's going on ?