# Import multiple CSV files in R columnwise

Tags: r, csv, import, reshape

[image]I am reshaping my question,

I need to import several CSV files of 296x2 (296 rows x 2 columns) into a single dataset.

First column is the same for all files.

I would like to merge all the CSV into a single dataset columnwise (conserving only the first column as row name once.
In other words, All the 329 CSV files are comma delimited and are all the same 296x2. I would like to end up with a 296x329 dataset that includes the second column of each dataset.

Thanks in advance
Emiliano

Comment: How have you 'merged' the data in the first place? Perhaps you should be using `cbind` to put your data together?

Comment: Yeah probably I should! I will write down in the post how did I do, Thanks

Comment: Without seeing your data or the code you've written it's hard to help you. Have a read of [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5977215) - you're more likely to get assistance if other people can see what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your data it's difficult to say, but assume you have your dataset in a folder name: C:/foo/. Try this one:

```
filenames <- list.files('C:/foo/', pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
la <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)


Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="Wavelength"), la)
```

Comment: Thanks eddie, you lines managed to import everything together only in single huge column tough :( all the 329 CSV files are comma delimited and are all the same 296x2. I would like to end up with a 296x329 dataset that includes the second column of each dataset :)

Comment: oh, are the first column is same for all the files?

Comment: Try this one and let me know please?  dataset <- do.call("merge",append(lapply(file_list, read.csv, header = TRUE), by= c("First coloumn name" )

Comment: Hello Eddie, yes the first column is the same for all. I am failing to compile the lines ,    Error: unexpected symbol in:
"dataset <- do.call("merge",append(lapply(file_list, read.csv, header = TRUE, by= c("Wavelength" )
dataset"

Comment: I think I found the solution, I edited the answer, Please try this one and let me know.

Comment: Thanks eddie, I am still having issues, dont get why, when i run the reduce operation,  I get:  Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1024.0 Mb In addition: There were 32 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: I have attached the header of one of my excel files in case it could result useful

Comment: I tried in a small dataset and it worked. There are some tricks to manage memory in R http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session?rq=1