# R: HUGE memory requirement applying variance structure to gls in nlme package

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, variance, nlme

I created a model using the `gls` function of the `nlme` package in R.
I then attempted to add fixed variance structure to the model using the `weights` argument.

However, I get an error about memory allocation that just seems, well, extreme.

> Error in glsEstimate(object, control = control) : 
>     'Calloc' could not allocate memory (18446744073709551616 of 8 bytes)

**Any suggestions about what to do with this??**

---

Context:

- My Code:

  ```
  mod <- read.csv('mod.ht.dat.csv', head = T)
  dim(mod)
  [1] 90826     8

  library(nlme)
  lm3 <- gls(HT ~ D * I(D^2), data = mod, na.action = na.omit, method = 'ML')
  vf1Fixed <- varFixed(~D)
  lm2 <- update(lm3, . ~ ., weights = vf1Fixed)
  Error in glsEstimate(object, control = control) : 
    'Calloc' could not allocate memory (18446744073709551616 of 8 bytes)
  ```

  -- Note: model format is from [Zuur et al. (2009)](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-0-387-87458-6).
- My memory usage (using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session)) and memory limit:

  ```
  > lsos()
                   Type     Size    PrettySize  Rows Columns
  lm3               gls 12361512 [1] "11.8 Mb"    16      NA
  mod.ht.dat data.frame  4002768  [1] "3.8 Mb" 90826       8
  vf1Fixed     varFixed     1024    [1] "1 Kb"     0      NA

  > memory.limit()
  [1] 8182
  ```
- Session Info:

  ```
  R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
  Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
  Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
  ```

The necessary allocated memory seems ridiculously high for what I'm doing.

I've modified the code by using `gls` directly (vs. `update`), I've placed `varFixed` in *and* outside of the model call itself, I've creatd a nw variable for D^2 before the model call, I've cleared my memory, I've restarted my computer, etc....Nothing seems to bring this HUGE number down.

**Is it possible that adding this fixed variance structure to the model *really* is that memory intensive?? Or is perhaps something else going on here that I'm missing?...**

---

**UPDATE**:

As requested in comments:

```
>traceback()

8: glsEstimate(object, control = control)
7: Initialize.glsStruct(glsSt, dataMod, glsEstControl)
6: Initialize(glsSt, dataMod, glsEstControl)
5: gls(model = HT ~ D + I(D^2) + D:I(D^2), data = mod, method = "ML", 
   na.action = na.omit, weights = vf1Fixed)
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(call, parent.frame())
2: update.gls(lm3, . ~ ., weights = vf1Fixed)
1: update(lm3, . ~ ., weights = vf1Fixed)

>dput(head(mod,5))

structure(list(HT = c(3.7, 8.7, 10.1, 4, 8.7), SPEC = structure(c(53L, 
53L, 53L, 53L, 53L), .Label = c("ACBA", "ACER", "ACRU", "AESY", 
"AIAL", "ALJU", "AMAR", "BENI", "CACA", "CACO", "CACR", "CAFL", 
"CAGL", "CAOL", "CAOV", "CAPA", "CARY", "CATO", "CECA", "CELA", 
"CEOC", "CHVI", "COFL", "CRAT", "CRMA", "DIVI", "ELPU", "ELUM", 
"EUAM", "FAGR", "FRAX", "GLTR", "HAVI", "ILAM", "ILDE", "ILOP", 
"JUNI", "JUVI", "LIBE", "LIJA", "LISI", "LIST", "LITU", "LOMA", 
"MAGR", "MATR", "MORU", "NYSY", "OSVI", "OXAR", "PATO", "PIEC", 
"PITA", "PIVI", "PLOC", "PRSE", "QUAL", "QUCO", "QUER", "QUFA", 
"QULY", "QUMA", "QUPH", "QURG", "QURU", "QUST", "QUVE", "RHCO", 
"SAAL", "STGR", "ULAL", "ULAM", "ULRU", "UNKN", "VAAR", "VACC", 
"VACO", "VAST", "VIAC", "VIBR", "VIPR", "VIRA", "VIRU"), class = "factor"), 
    D = c(4.1, 6.9, 7.4, 6.9, 13.7), plot = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L), tree_age = c(9L, 13L, 16L, 9L, 13L), Year = c(1933L, 
    1937L, 1940L, 1933L, 1937L), StaticLineID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L), D2 = c(16.81, 47.61, 54.76, 47.61, 187.69)), .Names = c("HT", 
"SPEC", "D", "plot", "tree_age", "Year", "StaticLineID", "D2"
), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

**Update 2:**

Just to note: I tried applying a completely different type of variance structure to my data to see how my computer handled what I would have assumed to be a relatively similarly memory-intensive procedure.

- This time I added varIdent variance structure:

  ```
  >vf2 <- varIdent(form = ~ 1 | SPEC)
  >lm22 <- update(lm3, . ~ ., weights = vf2)
  ```

Although it took forever to run (and ended up with a convergence error), it did not immediately produce the memory-allocation error as the former varFixed coding did.

Comment: Could you also include output of `traceback()` and if possible  `dput(head(mod,5))` to glimpse at data structure

Comment: @Osssan : See update. I've added output from both `traceback` and `dput`.

Comment: Try what happens if you use a third-degree orthogonal polynomial (see the poly function) instead of this strange interaction between a linear and a quadratic effect of the same variable. Your model doesn't seem very sensible.

Comment: @Roland: Even when I remove the "interaction" between linear and quadratic effects, I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? I don't think you'll get an answer without one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION: Remove 0-values from the variance covariate**

Well I'm still not sure *why* it's happening (though I'm assuming a closer look at `varFixed` might tell me), but I found the issue.

There were 3 instances in which D = 0.

(More generally, there were 0 values in the variable (the so called *variance covariate*) I was trying to use to generate my fixed variance structure).

Once I removed these 3 trees with 0-values from my training data, the model ran as expected (and almost immediately).

[Note: these trees all represent data collection errors, so it was ok to "throw them out"].

Comment: OK, so you had assigned infinite weights.