# Is there anyway I can check which R objects takes too much memory?

Tags: mysql, r, memory-leaks, web-scraping

Now I am using R to integrate different stock information(like RCurl for Web info and quantmod for financial report and trade info)

After I get data I put them in MySQL database.

The program works find BUT after loop some time the R session consumes too much memory(some 1000 stocks takes 4GB memory)

Is there anyway in R I can check which objects takes the most memory? Or is there any tools I can check the possible memory leak problem? Thanks!

Comment: See the [Previous SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session)

Comment: Are you growing an object in a loop?

Comment: yes, the basic logic in a loop is: download html code, parse it and extract value i want, load it into an object then write to it to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Great thought. I would encourage taking a look at Hadley Wickham's article on R memory use at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html.  A Couple of notes:

- You can find an object size by using the function `object_size(x)` from the `pryr` package
- You can find the total size of all objects in memory with `mem_used()` from the pryr package
- There is an <s>awesome package called lineprof</s> (now deprecated in favour of `profvis`) that allows you to see memory use at every line of your code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks jean and others, I have read all references you offered before, it helps. Since I use the XML package to parse html code and it seems it is the most suspicious one! As recommends, I use xml2 package to replace XML, it works *almost* fine which it dramatically low the consumption of memory. Maybe the lower growth rate of memory seizing is caused by other reasons.

Comment: I am using xml2::read_html to replace RCurl::getURL; using xml_find_all to replace XML::getNodeSet(which seems the most suspicious function cause memory leaks). then use xml_remove(x, free = TRUE) to free memory explicitly. hope this helps.