# Writing a loop and initializing various class of objects

Tags: r

I am processing a large file, I read in chucks of it and process it and save what I extract. Then after `rm(list=ls())` to clear memory *(sometime have to use .rs.restartR() as well but that is not of concern in this post)*, I run the same script **after adding 1** in two numbers in my script.

This seemed like a opportunity to try writing a loop but - between trying to initialize all the object that are used in the loop and given that I am not very good with writing loops it got really confusing.

I posted this here to hear some suggestion, I apologize in advance if my question is too vague.  Thanks.

```
#######################         A:11
#######################         B:12

                # A    I change the multiple each time here.
text_tbl <- fread("tlm_s_words", skip = 166836*11, nrows = 166836, header = FALSE, col.names = "text")



bi_tkn_one <- tokens(text_tbl$text, what = "fastestword", ngrams = 4, concatenator =" ", verbose = TRUE)

dfm_1 <- dfm(bi_tkn_one)

## First use colSums(), saves a numeric vector in `final_dfm_1`
## tib is the desired oject I will save with new name ea. time.

final_dfm_1 <- colSums(dfm_1)


tib <- tbl_df(final_dfm_1) %>% add_rownames()  
# This is what I wanted to extract 'the freq of each token'


            # B Here I change the name `tib`` is saved uneder each time.
saveRDS(tib, file = "tiq12.Rda")

rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
Sys.sleep(10)
gc()
Sys.sleep(10)
```

Below I will run the same script but change 11 to 12 in `fread()`, and change 12 to 13 in `saveRDS()` command.

```
#######################         A:12
#######################         b:13

            # A    I change the multiple each time here.
text_tbl <- fread("tlm_s_words", skip = 166836*12, nrows = 166836, header = FALSE, col.names = "text")



bi_tkn_one <- tokens(text_tbl$text, what = "fastestword", ngrams = 4, concatenator =" ", verbose = TRUE)

dfm_1 <- dfm(bi_tkn_one)

## Using colSums(), gives a numeric vector`final_dfm_1`
## tib is the desired oject I will save with new name each time.

final_dfm_1 <- colSums(dfm_1)


tib <- tbl_df(final_dfm_1) %>% add_rownames()  
# This is what I wanted to extract 'the freq of each token'


            # B Here I change the name `tib`` is saved uneder each time.
saveRDS(tib, file = "tiq13.Rda")

rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
Sys.sleep(10)
gc()
Sys.sleep(10)
```

Below is a list of all the objects (thanks [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session)) in my working environment, that  are cleared from the working environment before running the the same chunk with A+1, and B+1.

```
                  Type      Size    Rows Columns
dfm_1        dfmSparse 174708600  166836 1731410
bi_tkn_one      tokens 152494696  166836      NA
tib             tbl_df 148109248 1731410       2
final_dfm_1    numeric 148108544 1731410      NA
text_tbl    data.table  22485264  166836       1
```

I spent some time trying to figure out how to write this loop, found a post on SO about how to initialize a `data.table` with a `character` column, but there are still other objects that I think I need to initialize.  I am unsure of how plausible it is to write such a loop.

I have copied and pasted the same script back-to-back as shown above and run it all at once.  It's silly, since I am just adding one in two places.

Feel free comment on my approach, I would like to learn something out of this.  Best

On a side note: I read about adding `.rs.restartR()` to the loop, and came across post that suggested using batch-files or scheduling tasks in R, I will have to pass on learning those for now.

Comment: I think restarting R is pointless, this could all be done in a single session. So, I agree, what you are doing is silly. In particular, I doubt if clearing your namespace will do anything - you would get the same effect just by assigning new values to those variables. And, yes of course you should write a loop, and no, it's not complicated. In fact, you should not even think of learning R without learning how to write a loop! That's like learning to drive a car without learning how to turn left. So... why not post an attempt at it?

Comment: @dash2 - This was very simple,  _ I didn't have to initialize any objects_ , must have been doing something when I first tried to run this.  And I see your point that there is no point of clearing namespace.

Comment: That has me thinking when do I need to initialize objects for the loops

Answer (score 0):

This was very simple, *I didn't have to initialize any objects* , that is what I was trying to do.  Only things I had to load was the required packages upon starting R and run the loop.

```
 ls()
    character(0)
From an empty environment, just a simple loop.

library(data.table)
library(quanteda)
library(dplyr)

    for (i in 4:19){
                    # A    I change the multiple each time here.
        text_tbl <- fread("tlm_s_words", skip = 166836*i, nrows = 166836, header = FALSE, col.names = "text")



        bi_tkn_one <- tokens(text_tbl$text, what = "fastestword", ngrams = 3, concatenator =" ", verbose = TRUE)

        dfm_1 <- dfm(bi_tkn_one)

        ## Using colSums(), gives a numeric vector`final_dfm_1`
        ## tib is the desired oject I will save with new name each time.

        final_dfm_1 <- colSums(dfm_1)
        print(setNames(length(final_dfm_1), "no. N-grams in this batch"))
            # no. N-grams


        tib <- tbl_df(final_dfm_1) %>% add_rownames()  
        # This is what I wanted to extract 'the freq of each token'


             # B Here I change the name `tib`` is saved uneder each time.
        iplus = i+1
        saveRDS(tib, file = paste0("titr",iplus,".Rda"))

        rm(list=ls())
        Sys.sleep(10)
        gc()
        Sys.sleep(10)

    }
```

Without initializing any data.table, or other objects the result of above loop was 16 files saved in my working directory.

That makes me think, *when do we need to initialize vectors, matrices and other objects that are used to our loop?*

Comment: An interesting question if it hasn't been asked already. In general, the only reason to do that is to save time/memory. Take a look at the R Inferno chapter 2  for more details: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf . BTW, why the `Sys.sleep(10)`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to 'Inferno', first impression is I could learn a ton here, not to mention, I am confused about which resource to focus on at this to master R, by the first looks 'Inferno' i first help me defrag what I already know and then lead me comfort with advanced topics.

Comment: `Sys.sleep(10)` was introduced because some chunks I ran were consuming  90% or more of my RAM and wanted to try something let memory to clear from `rm()`, it was just a shot in the dark - to be frank I was trying to be sensitive towards my laptop, let it breathe before drowning it into another intense processing.

Comment: You need a `Give.laptop.sugar.lump()` function... but seriously, what's wrong with using your RAM? That's what it is there for. Ditto with the `gc()` call unless you actually know you need it.

Comment: The amount of mistakes I am making, I ought to resort to step back n say Wuusaa more often.  Best