# Memory leak and C wrapper

Tags: r, memory-leaks

I am currently using the `sbrl()` function from the [sbrl](https://github.com/cran/sbrl/) library. The function does the job of any supervised statistical learning algorithm: it takes data, and generates a predictive model.

I have a memory leak issue when using it.

- If I run the function in a loop, my RAM will get filled more and more, although I am always pointing to the same object.
- Eventually, my computer will reach the RAM limit and crash.
- Calling `gc()` will never help. Only closing the R session releases the memory.

Below is a minimal reproducible example. An eye should be kept on the system's memory management program.

Importantly, the `sbrl()` function calls, from what I can tell, `C` code, and also makes use of `Rcpp`. I guess this relates to the memory leak issue.

Would you know how to force memory to be released?

Configuration: Windows 10, R 3.5.0 (Rstudio or R.exe)

```
install.packages("sbrl")
library(sbrl)

# Getting / prepping data
data("tictactoe")

# Looping over sbrl
for (i in 1:1e3) {
  rules <- sbrl(
    tdata = tictactoe, iters=30000, pos_sign="1", 
    neg_sign="0", rule_minlen=1, rule_maxlen=3, 
    minsupport_pos=0.10, minsupport_neg=0.10, 
    lambda=10.0, eta=1.0, alpha=c(1,1), nchain=20
  )
  invisible(gc())
  cat("Rules object size in Mb:", object.size(rules)/1e6, "\n")
}
```

Comment: This may help [Tricks to manage the available memory in an R session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1358003/9898745)

Comment: It looks like this should be reported as an issue to the maintainer. According to the checks there is a [valgrind error](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/bdr/memtests/valgrind/sbrl/sbrl-Ex.Rout) which is associated with memory leaks.

Comment: Many thanks for the checks, Emil, this is great. I will contact the maintainer, then.

Comment: I am removing the `rcpp` tag which looks spurious here