# list of objects with characteristic "num" or $dim

Tags: r, list, attributes

```
 ls()
```

in my environment will give me the list of all objects. But I have generated vectors, for which if I run
attributes(object)  I get $dim.
Is there a way to select the object with this attributes?
I had a look to rlist package without success.
thanks.

Comment: I've used the function in Dirk's post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session. It doesn't necessarily filter based on object type/class, but it does clearly show what objects have the `dim` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select all objects with a `dim` attribute, then you can do something like this ...

```
m <- matrix(0, 2, 2)  # has a dim attribute
v <- 1:5              # does not have a dim attribute

Filter(function(x) !is.null(dim(x)), as.list(.GlobalEnv))
# $m
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
# [2,]    0    0
```

Since a call to `dim` will return `NULL` for objects with no dimension attribute, we ask for the objects that do not return `NULL` and filter them out of the environment object list.