# How to increase the allocated memory size for RStudio in MAC?

Tags: r, memory-management

I tried the functions `memory.limit()` and `memory.size()` but those are windows specific.

I want the similar function for MAC by which I can increase the memory of RStudio.

Comment: `?gc()` perhaps ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session?rq=1 maybe?

Comment: What memory limit do you have? Usually, it should the available physical memory in your system. Or do you want to use virtual memory?

Comment: Usually the limit is just how ever much RAM is in your computer. Are you trying to load data that's larger than your available RAM? What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have 16 GB RAM in MAC but i am not able to get any function which can tell me RStudio is using how much memory and how can I increase it.

Comment: I am unable to make plots of the package fpc which is used for plotting cluster. It works fine on windows after increasing the memory(memory.limit).