# How to deal with error about memory limitation with biglm function to ffdf object

Tags: r, lm, ff

I have a large `ffdf` object in R. It contains x and y values, and each column has 71,998,512 values.

I am trying to apply `biglm` function in `biglm` package as below

```
dat <- ffdf(Back = Pitch_Back$V1,  Head = Pitch_Head$V1)            
fit_linear <- biglm(Back ~ Head, data = dat)
```

But I came across the memory limit error as below;

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 549.3 Mb

How can I deal with it?

Comment: the not so serious - but totally pragmatic answer is that with 2 variables and 77 million points if you sample about 1% of your data your model will be about 99.999 ...% similar to the model built on all the data.

Comment: the serious secondary answers are mostly to be found to this previously question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1358003/1527403

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to try it.