# How to use lapply to size objects in environment?

Tags: r, list, character, lapply

I want to make a table with all the dim() of objects in the environment.  ls() returns a list of characters which lapply will not take as object names and operate properly on.  What to do? Using R.

```
> lapply(ls(), dim)
```

just returns

```
[[1]]
NULL
```

Comment: I'm using R ... was hoping to create a table of row x col lengths of each of the objects in the environment

Comment: `lapply(mget(ls()), dim) %>% as.data.frame()`

Comment: `ls()` doesn't return a list, but a vector of character.

Comment: There are some applicable functions provided in answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/1358003/3358272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use **parse** and **eval** to change the string vector to env objects and then use **dim**.

```
lapply(ls(), function(x) dim(eval(parse(text=x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Use `eapply` and then optionally use `Filter` to remove components with no dim.  This creates a named list with the dimensions in the corresponding components.

```
Filter(length, eapply(.GlobalEnv, dim))
```

**2)** A variation would be to create a matrix result such that the row names are the variable names.

```
do.call("rbind", eapply(.GlobalEnv, dim))
```

**3)** or to restrict the output to data frames and not arrays (as arrays might cause problems if there are arrays not of two dimensions) then:

```
df_dim <- function(x) if (is.data.frame(x)) dim(x)
do.call("rbind", eapply(.GlobalEnv, df_dim))
```

**4)** or to restrict it to objects having 2 dimensions including both data frames and arrays:

```
two_dim <- function(x, dimx = dim(x)) if (length(dimx) == 2) dimx
do.call("rbind", eapply(.GlobalEnv, two_dim))
```

or

```
do.call("rbind", Filter(function(x) length(x) == 2, eapply(.GlobalEnv, dim)))
```