# How to find heavy objects that are not stored in .GlobalEnv?

Tags: r, memory, environment-variables, workspace

I am trying to find which objects are taking a lot of memory in my R session, but the problem is that the object might have been invisibly created with an unknown name in an unknown environment.

If the object is stored in `.GlobalEnv` or a known environment, I can easily use a strategy like `ls(enviro)+get()+object.size()` (see `lsos` on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) for example) to list all objects and their size, allowing me to identify the heavy objects.

However, the object in question might not be stored in `.GlobalEnv`, but might be in some obscure environment implicitly created by an external package. How can in that case identify which object is using a lot of RAM?

The best case study is `ggplot2` creating `.last_plot` in a dedicated environment. Looking under the hood one can find that it is stored in `environment(ggplot2:::.store$get)`, so one can find it and eventually remove it. But if I didn't know that location or name a priori, would there be a way to find that there is a heavy object called `.last_plot` somewhere in memory?

```r
pryr::mem_used()
#> 34.7 MB

## example: implicit creation of heavy and hidden object by ggplot
path <- tempfile() 
if(!file.exists(path)){
  saveRDS(as.data.frame(matrix(rep(1,1e07), ncol=5)), path)
}

pryr::mem_used()
#> 34.9 MB
p1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(readr::read_rds(path), ggplot2::aes(V1))
rm(p1)
pryr::mem_used()
#> 127 MB

## Hidden object is not in .GlobalEnv
ls(.GlobalEnv, all.names = TRUE)
#> [1] "path"

## Here I know where to find it: environment(ggplot2:::.store$get)
ls(all.names = TRUE, envir = environment(ggplot2:::.store$get))
#> [1] ".last_plot"

pryr::object_size(get(".last_plot", environment(ggplot2:::.store$get))$data)
#> 80 MB

## But how could I have found this otherwise?
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's any existing way to do this.  If you combine @AllanCameron's answer with my comment, where you'd also run `ls(y)` for `y` environments calculated as

```
ns <- loadedNamespaces()
for (x in ns) {
   y <- loadNamespace(x)
   # look at the size of everything in y
}
```

you still won't find all the environments.  I *think* you could do it if you also examined every object that might contain a reference to an environment (e.g. every function, formula, list, and various exotic objects) but it would be tricky not to miss something or count things more than once.

Edited to add:  Actually, `pryr::object_size` is pretty smart at reporting on the environments attached to objects, so we'd get close by searching namespaces.  For example, to find the top 20 objects:

```r
pryr::mem_used()
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'pryr':
#>   method      from
#>   print.bytes Rcpp
#> 35 MB
path <- tempfile() 
if(!file.exists(path)){
  saveRDS(as.data.frame(matrix(rep(1,1e07), ncol=5)), path)
}
pryr::mem_used()
#> 35.2 MB
p1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(readr::read_rds(path), ggplot2::aes(V1))
rm(p1)
pryr::mem_used()
#> 127 MB
envs <- c(globalenv = globalenv(),
          sapply(loadedNamespaces(), function(ns) loadNamespace(ns)))
sizes <- lapply(envs, function(e) {
                        objs <- ls(e, all = TRUE)
                        sapply(objs, function(obj) pryr::object_size(get(obj, envir = e)))
                })
head(sort(unlist(sizes), decreasing = TRUE), 20)
#>       base..__S3MethodsTable__.      utils..__S3MethodsTable__. 
#>                        96216872                        83443704 
#>       grid..__S3MethodsTable__.    ggplot2..__S3MethodsTable__. 
#>                        80945520                        80636768 
#>                  ggplot2..store             methods..classTable 
#>                        80418936                        10101152 
#>   graphics..__S3MethodsTable__.           tools..check_packages 
#>                         9325608                         5185880 
#>         compiler.inlineHandlers           methods..genericTable 
#>                         3444600                         2808440 
#>         Rcpp..__T__show:methods   colorspace..__T__show:methods 
#>                         2474672                         2447880 
#>                 Rcpp..RcppClass Rcpp..__C__C++OverloadedMethods 
#>                         2127584                         1990504 
#>            Rcpp..__C__RcppClass             Rcpp..__C__C++Field 
#>                         1982576                         1980176 
#>       Rcpp..__C__C++Constructor               Rcpp..__T__$:base 
#>                         1979992                         1939616 
#>         tools..install_packages               Rcpp..__C__Module 
#>                         1904032                         1899872
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I don't know why those methods tables come out so large (I suspect it's because `ggplot2` adds methods to those tables, so its environment gets captured); but somehow they are finding your object, because they aren't so big if I don't create it.

A hint about the issue is in the 5th object, listed as `ggplot2..store`  (i.e. the object named `.store` in the `ggplot2` namespace).  Doesn't tell you to look in the environments of the functions in `.store`, but at least it gets you started.

Second edit:

Here are some tweaks to make the output a bit more readable.

```r
# Unlist first, so we can clean up the names
sizes <- unlist(sizes)

# Replace the first dot with :::
names(sizes) <- sub(".", ":::", names(sizes), fixed = TRUE)

# Remove internal R objects
keep <- !grepl(".__", names(sizes), fixed = TRUE)
sizes <- sizes[keep]
```

With these changes, the output from `sort(sizes[keep], decreasing = TRUE)` starts out as

```r
                ggplot2:::.store 
                        80418936 
            base:::.userHooksEnv 
                        47855920 
                 base:::.Options 
                        45016888 
                   utils:::Rprof 
                        44958416
```

Comment: nice, sounds like a solid hint to navigate in that jungle! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```r
unlist(lapply(search(), function(y) sapply(ls(y), function(x) object.size(get(x)))))
```

You will get a complete list of all the objects in all the environments on your search path, including their sizes. You can then sort these and find the offending objects.

Comment: This is unfortunately not working with my reprex? Did it for you? Note that using `ggplot2::` will imply that the package is not even in search! And even if it were in search, I don't think it is in the ggplot environment, but in an enviro created by ggplot? And finally, the call `ls()` will need `all.names=TRUE` to be complete? Thanks!

Comment: But that's not all the objects:  for example, the example code in the question doesn't put `ggplot2` on the search path.  You would also want to look through `loadedNamespaces()` (carefully, there's some overlap).