# Cannot allocate vector of size 16.4 Mb R

Tags: r, memory

I have been working with almost the same data in R for a couple month and now I suddenly got this error message when I tried to import a dataset I have imported many times before.

What can I do?

I have tried
`memory.size()`and `memory.limit()`. However, I am not sure that I used it right.

Thank you very much in advance!
Anna

Comment: Welcome to SO, AnnaLatysheva! I don't know that we can help much knowing nothing about the data, the packages you're using, or the code or processes at work. R generally does a reasonable job of "garbage collection" for memory management; if it's suddenly not working, perhaps `ls.objects()` will clearly show any unused and large data objects you have sitting in your environment. Lacking that, you might try restarting R *without a project or `.Rdata` file* (as that can easily contain the memory-hogging objects). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for involvement! There are different types of data I have this problem with, data from Stata and datasets I made myself in R, which is semicolon separated. I start the program (so there are any other data in environment from last session) and when I try to import data I get this message that R is not able to allocate the vector of some size.  I have tried ```ls.objects()```as you said, however it seems like this function does not exist. I am new to R, may be I misunderstood what you ment.

Comment: oops, sorry .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session has some funcs for list objects and their sizes. In fact, that question is very much about managing memory in R. It seems an appropriate read for your dilemma!

Comment: One of the answers there is from MattDoyle, one of the authors/contributors to the `data.table` package. I deal with large-ish data (1-4M rows) every day, and when I switched to `data.table`, many things sped up considerably. The learning curve is a little steep, but once you get it, perhaps using that package can help mitigate some memory issues on your end.