# Display a time clock in the R command line

Tags: r, time, clock

I wonder if there is a way to display the current time in the R command line, like in MS DOS, we can use

```
Prompt $T $P$G
```

to include the time clock in every prompt line. 
Something like

```
options(prompt=paste(format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S"),"> "))
```

will do it, but then it is fixed at the time it was set. I'm not sure how to make it update automatically.

Comment: None of the current callback-based answers does the same thing as the MS DOS prompt, because they depend on the execution of a top-level command.  If one simply presses CR/LF in the console, it will not update the time, while this will be updated in MS DOS.

Comment: Where I'm sitting I can see the time on my screen clock, my wristwatch, my trusty old Palm VX, and my phone. Do you really need another reminder of your increasing mortality? :) Is it really just for timestamping your activity?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, that's what I'd do.  Sometimes I run a command from the console, and would like to know when it ended, if I've stepped away.  The other methods do that reasonably well, but then I still have to check the clock time (or execute a new command).  I have a lot of profiling, logging, messaging, etc., so this prompt thing could be superfluous, but what the heck.  :)  In any case, I thought it best to solve the question that was asked.

Answer (score 52):

Chase points the right way as `options("prompt"=...)` can be used for this.  But his solutions adds a *constant* time expression which is not what we want.

The documentation for the function `taskCallbackManager` has the rest:

```
R> h <- taskCallbackManager()
R> h$add(function(expr, value, ok, visible) { 
+     options("prompt"=format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S> ")); 
+             return(TRUE) }, 
+     name = "simpleHandler")
[1] "simpleHandler"
07:25:42> a <- 2
07:25:48>
```

We register a callback that gets evaluated after each command completes. That does the trick.  More fancy documentation is [in this document](http://developer.r-project.org/TaskHandlers.pdf) from the R developer site.

Comment: Ooops, just fixed the URL to Duncan TL's write-up.

Comment: @Dirk : Wonderful, thx for the pointer to that function. Yet, this solution still has a -minor- bug in it: when you have an error, it doesn't update the time. Try f <- function() { Sys.sleep(1) ; stop() } - and then - f() . Not that I would have known how to do that though...

Comment: Thanks Dirk and Joris! @Joris: could you elaborate a little further on updating the time when there is an error. I tried function() { Sys.sleep(1) ; stop() }, but it did not seem to work.

Comment: @Shu : if you use Dirks solution and afterwards you try that function I gave, you see that the time is not updated. The callback does not get evaluated when the command issues an error. But that's a very tiny minor inconvenience I just liked to mention for hairsplitting sake ;-)

Comment: Thanks Joris, Dirks solution is very helpful, just I am a bit greedy for more as someone would like me to provide time information of error reported in the R console. Wondering if it is possible.

Comment: @Shu : If you need the time between the command is given and the error is reported, use system.time(). It tells you when exactly the timing stopped.

Comment: This doesn't work on my mac (running 2.14) in the GUI but it does work when R is launched as a terminal app.  Any ideas why?

Comment: GUIs interfere with event loops, and hence muck up the callback scheme.

Comment: Unfortunately, a callback that depends on a top level execution will not update with CR/LF, unlike the DOS prompt. This is where `tcltk2` has some neat stuff.

Comment: How can I add this to something like my `.Rprofile` so it loads every time, in every project?

Comment: I had to assign the handler (and helper function it calls) to .GlobalEnv in .Rprofile - perhaps because I did this all in an if (interactive()) {} block.

Answer (score 19):

None of the other methods, which are based on callbacks, will update the prompt *unless* a top-level command is executed.  So, pressing return in the console will not create a change.  Such is the nature of R's standard callback handling.

If you install the `tcltk2` package, you can set up a task scheduler that changes the `option()` as follows:

```
library(tcltk2)
tclTaskSchedule(1000, {options(prompt=paste(Sys.time(),"> "))}, id = "ticktock", redo = TRUE)
```

Voila, something like the MS DOS prompt.

NB: Inspiration came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8842166/805808).

---

Note 1: The wait time (1000 in this case) refers to the # of milliseconds, not seconds.  You might adjust it downward when sub-second resolution is somehow useful.

Answer (score 18):

Here is an alternative callback solution:

```
updatePrompt <- function(...) {options(prompt=paste(Sys.time(),"> ")); return(TRUE)}
addTaskCallback(updatePrompt)
```

This works the same as Dirk's method, but the syntax is a bit simpler to me.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither is precisely like the DOS prompt, which would be updated even when the return key is pressed.  The callbacks only wait for a top level execution. To learn how to do it via a clock trigger, I created a solution with the `tcltk2` package.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the default character that is displayed through the `options()` command. You may want to try something like this:

```
options(prompt = paste(Sys.time(), ">"))
```

Check out the help page for `?options` for a full list of things you can set. It is a very useful thing to know about!

Assuming this is something you want to do for every R session, consider moving that to your `.Rprofile`. Several other good nuggets of programming happiness can be found [hither](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile) on that topic.

Comment: Actually, not quite. You get the *constant* time expression of when `options("prompt"=...)` was set. You need a callback as shown in my answer.

Comment: It's the solution OP gave and didn't like. But the reference to the Rprofile is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a native R function for doing this, but I know R has interfaces with other languages that do have system time commands. Maybe this is an option?

Thierry mentioned `system.time()` and there is also `proc.time()` depending on what you need it for, although neither of these give you the current time.