# Time stamp at R prompt possible?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R: Display a time clock in the R command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222476/r-display-a-time-clock-in-the-r-command-line)

Is there any way to configure R so that it will display a time stamp before the prompt ">"?

Thanks a lot
EC

Comment: It's worth knowing that it's *even simpler* than the code used in the answer in that question.

Comment: @JohnColby -- Very good point. Yours *is* simpler in my view (even though the help page for `addTaskCallback` claims the opposite).

Comment: The *question* is still a dup though, so, I don't know, maybe I should just comment over there?

Comment: @JohnColby Closing this as a dup is nothing to be afraid of; although it's _possible_ it could end up being deleted, that's unlikely since both questions have good answers that should be kept, and it might be a good merge candidate.

Comment: @JohnColby: you could answer the other question with your less verbose solution.  I voted to close because I prefer answers be in one place, rather than spread across multiple questions.

Comment: @JohnColby -- For the time being, I put a link over there to this answer as an alternative solution.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien OK done. Thanks, Josh and Josh!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will do it:

```
options(prompt=paste(Sys.time(),"> "))
```

I forget how to make it update though. I'll try to check when I get a sec...

Ahh found it:

```
updatePrompt <- function(...) {options(prompt=paste(Sys.time(),"> ")); return(TRUE)}
addTaskCallback(updatePrompt)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, doesn't seem to get updated: 2011-12-12 19:07:22 > Sys.time()
[1] "2011-12-12 19:08:00 CET"
2011-12-12 19:07:22 > Sys.time()
[1] "2011-12-12 19:08:01 CET"
2011-12-12 19:07:22 > Sys.time()
[1] "2011-12-12 19:08:02 CET"
2011-12-12 19:07:22 > Sys.time()
[1] "2011-12-12 19:08:03 CET"
2011-12-12 19:07:22 > Sys.time()
[1] "2011-12-12 19:08:03 CET"
2011-12-12 19:07:22 > Sys.time()
[1] "2011-12-12 19:08:04 CET"
2011-12-12 19:07:22 > Sys.time()
[1] "2011-12-12 19:08:04 CET"
2011-12-12 19:07:22 > Sys.time()
[1] "2011-12-12 19:08:05 CET"
2011-12-12 19:07:22 >

Comment: This doesn't work on my mac using 2.14 in the GUI but it does work if I work with R from the terminal.