# Hook into Rgui console?

Tags: r, rgui

Is it possible to change the behaviour of R console such that, for instance

- before each command execution a `fortune()` is printed, or
- similar to `browser()`, the prompt is altered, and some new commands (c,n,Q) are introduced?

I am looking for an alternative to `readline()` that keeps the history function (key up) intact.

I am using R on winxp with Rgui, but a portable solution would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though it is independent of the GUI as just uses the callback mechanism as for example in the quesion on [R: Display a time clock in the R command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222476/r-display-a-time-clock-in-the-r-command-line).