# taskhandler that executes *before* the expr

Tags: r, callback, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a callback for running code *before* a prompt-entered `expr` is evaluated? (A search through SO, CRAN, and some googling has turned up what I suspect the answer to be: not possible with the current REPL implementation. My apologies if I missed a similarly-detailed duplicate discussion.)

I'm loosely familiar with `addTaskCallback()` and its family of functions. Reading the [help](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/taskCallback.html) and [developer docs](http://developer.r-project.org/TaskHandlers.pdf) tells me that the mechanism only runs *after* an expression is evaluated.

One eventual implementation is to provide a timing mechanism (either using `system.time()` or something more mundane); current methods (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222476/r-display-a-time-clock-in-the-r-command-line)) are helpful yet knowingly unaware of idle time.

Perhaps something akin to:

```
timerFunc <- local({
    .time <- 0
    function(expr, value, ok, visible) {
        if (missing(value)) {
            # called pre-evaluate
            .time <<- as.numeric(Sys.time())
        } else {
            # called post-evaluate
            gap <- as.numeric(Sys.time()) - .time
            if ( gap >= 10 ) {
                cat("##", gap, "seconds\n")
                # do something useful/meaningful
            }
        }
        return(TRUE)
    }
})
## this function does not exist (yet)
addPreTaskCallback(timerFunc)
## but this one does
addTaskCallback(timerFunc)
```

(This is merely example code without robustness and with a magic constant ... provided with brevity for discussion.)

I can think of several other contrived examples of how this could be used; though most are educational/academic, they are also arguably inefficient or lazy.

I'm guessing the overwhelming response will be "this should be on R-devel." If so, I believe this would attach somehow to `R_ReadConsole` (explained in [R-exts](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.pdf)). Thoughts?