# Permanently display a time clock in the R command line

Tags: r, time, clock

I am aware of how to add a timestamp during an R session using

```r
R> h <- taskCallbackManager()
R> h$add(function(expr, value, ok, visible) { 
+     options("prompt"=format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S> ")); 
+             return(TRUE) }, 
+     name = "simpleHandler")
[1] "simpleHandler"
07:25:42> a <- 2
```

as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222476/display-a-time-clock-in-the-r-command-line).

How can I make this a permanent feature, so that RStudio always has this as the prompt?

Comment: Please read [`?Startup`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/Startup) about a `~/.Rprofile` file.

Comment: I tried adding that text to my .Rprofile but it didn't do anything

Comment: inserting above into `.First <- function(){}` works for me.

Comment: Adam_G, after you added it to your `~/.Rprofile`, did you restart R? It worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to have a `.Rprofile` file in the `~/` (usually "C:/Users/me/Documents" in windows), and add the following into it.
It will show time as soon as you do something on the console.

```
.First <- function(){

   h <- taskCallbackManager()
   h$add(function(expr, value, ok, visible) { 
     options("prompt"=format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S> ")); 
     return(TRUE) }, name = "simpleHandler")
}
```

I think you could do this in the `Rprofile.site` in your
"C:\Program Files\R\R-x.x.x\etc" as well. As noted by @r2evans, this seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where that's located in OSX?

Comment: maybe just do `getwd()` after you start Rstudio? Also `setwd("~/")` should get you to "~/" as well.

Comment: @Adam_G `~/` is just the home directory; on a Mac that's usually something of the form `/Users/your_user_name` (just type `cd ~` and `pwd` to see the path).

Comment: You can find out where R thinks it should be with `normalizePath("~")`.

Comment: @Adam_G : Please read the help page you've already been referred to: It contains these sentences: "The path of this file is taken from the value of the R_PROFILE environment variable (after tilde expansion). If this variable is unset, the default is ‘R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site’, which is used if it exists (which it does not in a ‘factory-fresh’ installation). "

Comment: @Suren, putting configuration like this in the system-wide location such as within `c:/Program Files/R/` is not a good idea, for two reasons: (1) when you update R, it stops working; (2) if for any reasons there are other users on that machine, they are "forced" to use this as well. I know it's a backup recommendation, secondary to the `~/.Rprofile` location, but I still think it's a recommendation that flies against solid practices.

Comment: @r2evans thanks a lot. I didn't think about it that way.

Comment: Thank you for all of this advice. I tried placing the code in `~/.Rprofile`, and then restarted Rstudio, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Adam_G try `1 + 1` in the console and see if the time appears or not.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work now. I give up. But thank you!!