# How to disable "Save workspace image?" prompt in R?

Tags: r, read-eval-print-loop

When I exit the interactive R shell, it displays an annoying prompt every time:

```
>
>
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]: n
```

I'm always answering "no" to it, because if I wished to save my work, I'd do that *before* trying to exit.

How to get rid of the prompt?

---

<sup>Note: see `?save.image`</sup>

Comment: @Spacedman: it's Ctrl+Z in Windows, so don't ever try to "undo" anything. ;-)

Comment: In GNU/Linux, start `R --vanilla`

Comment: see also this answer using custom `q()` function in .Rprofie: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13043239/180892

Comment: for what it's worth, RStudio has a preferences hook for this

Comment: fwiw (also), this is the default behavior in the [radian](https://github.com/randy3k/radian) R console.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can pass the [`--no-save`](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-intro.html#Invoking-R-from-the-command-line) command line argument when you start R, or you can override the `q` function:

```
utils::assignInNamespace(
  "q", 
  function(save = "no", status = 0, runLast = TRUE) 
  {
    .Internal(quit(save, status, runLast))
  }, 
  "base"
)
```

Put the above code in your .Rprofile so it will be run on startup for every session.

Comment: +1 for `.Rprofile`, didn't know about it but thats really useful!

Comment: @Sacha So take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile

Comment: After I installed the Defaults package and added the above code to my Rprofile.site file (running R 2.15.1 on Windows 7), I get the following error: "Error in bindingIsLocked(name, as.environment(find(name))) : could not find function 'find'"

Comment: @JohnD.Cook: good point. Only the `base` package is available at that point, so I'd have to think about how to work around that.

Comment: @JohnD.Cook: See my edit for a solution to your comment.  Thanks for pointing out my error.

Comment: Run `install.packages("Defaults")` in R to install Defaults package first. It worked then on debian stable 6 with R 2.15

Comment: The Defaults package has apparently been removed.

Comment: I'm getting "Error: could not find function "assignInNamespace"". R 3.1.2 on OS X

Comment: @Josh Hansen add library(utils) to your .Rprofile to find assignInNamespace

Comment: I'm also getting `Error in utils::assignInNamespace("q", function(save = "no", status = 0,  :
  locked binding of ‘q’ cannot be changed` with `R v3.4.2` when I add it to my `.Rprofile` but do not get this error when I run the command in the terminal interactively.

Comment: @O.rka: are you putting the code inside an expression passed to `local()`? I get the same error when I do that, but it works if I put the code outside the `local()` call.

Comment: Let me **warn** you folks, using `library(foobar)` in `~/.Rprofile` has broken me a several builds invoked via `?install.packages` (during native C or Fortran compilation, the driver/wrapper scripts in R start to fail). Be ready to comment out, just in case.

Answer (score 53):

Haven't found the easiest Linux solution yet :)

On ubuntu add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias R='R --no-save'
```

Every time you start the R console with `R`, it will be passed the `--no-save` option.

Comment: Or as @aL3xa specified in a comment above use `R --vanilla` to combine `Combine  --no-save,  --no-restore,  --no-site-file,  --no-init-file and --no-environ`.

Comment: Don't forget to `reboot` server after updating `~/.bashrc`

Comment: I would use `alias r="R --no-save"`. I don't want to press `Shift` while typing `R`. @atsyplenkov: You don't need to reboot. You just need to type `source ~/.bash_aliases`.

Answer (score 30):

You can escape the "*Save workspace image?*" prompt with a <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

Thus, if you do <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> twice in interactive R, then you exit R without saving your workspace.

*(Tested on Linux and OS X)*

Comment: In R v4.1.3 on Windows, hitting Ctrl+D a second time gets you back to R's prompt.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Rgui, right-click on the icon you use to start R and click on "Properties", and add --no-save to the command that starts R.

(from http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/03/1115.html)

If you are using a different editor than Rgui, you have to pass --no-save to the R command line when starting R

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of properties tab?

Answer (score 10):

Overwrite default option for *save* argument of *quit* function

```
formals(quit)$save <- formals(q)$save <- "no"
```

put this line in .Rprofile

Edit: added `q`, so there is no prompt no matter which variant is used

Comment: > formals(quit)$save <- "no"
> q()
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]:

Answer (score 9):

If you're using R Studio IDE, you can do this by re-setting the global option.

Go to Tools --> Global Options --> R General (Basic)

1. Uncheck Restore .RData into your workspace at startup
2. Save workspace image to .RData on exit -- Select 'Never'
   [image: See screenshot below]

Click on 'Apply' and then 'Ok'

I've written a detailed post on this topic [here](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6786156716447830016)

In this post, I've addressed 'should we or should we not' save workspace image?
I've written detailed answer to the following questions in the comments (make sure you read them all):

1. How to set never save workspace image?
2. what does it really mean when it says ‘save workspace image’.
3. Why you should (almost always) not save workspace image?
4. When should I save workspace image?
5. If not saving the workspace image, what should I do? What are the best practices?

In some other posts, I've discussed that might be useful for R users are:

'What is reproducible work?'
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6789770117715640320

Why should you not use rm(list=ls())? R Best Practices
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6785805481131683840

Working directory
https://www.linkedin.com/posts/drnishaarora_2-set-working-directory-r-studio-activity-6785423883408297984-NAoH

Answer (score 8):

Get the best of both strategies given by users [1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/910868) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677):

Default to not save by adding the following line to your ~/.bashrc:

```
alias R='R --no-save'
```

But give yourself an easy way to save on exit by adding this to  ~/.Rprofile:

```
qs <- function() { q(save="yes") }
```

So now `q()` will quit without saving or prompting but `qs()` will save and quit (also without prompting)

Comment: I like it as `wq <- function() { q(save="yes")}` to mirror vi. (also, if you're writing an overwrite function, why not make it send a fixed argument)

Answer (score 6):

You could easily add a `qq()` function to the .Rprofile file

```
 qq <- function(save="no") { q(save=save)}
```

I thought that the save option was available with options, but apparently Joshua's answer is best.

Answer (score 3):

How about just avoiding the prompt by typing `q('no')` instead

Comment: .. which is even more keyboard hits than answering the prompt :-)

Answer (score 3):

If, like me, typing out a whole pair of brackets seems like too much effort to exit the repl you can try this:

```
exit <- structure(list(), class = "exit_command")

print.exit_command <- function(...) {
  q("no")  # exit without saving
}
```

This creates a new class, which causes R to exit when attempting to print said class. The upshot being that if you run `exit` in the R repl, the whole thing will exit (because it tries to print it).

NB: You can add it to `~/.Rprofile` to load at the start of every session.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an alias for the R command:

**using bash**: `alias R='R --no-save'`

**using csh:** `alias R 'R --no-save'`

Answer (score -3):

If you feel adventurous enough, you could also edit the `startup` section at the end of `/usr/bin/R`, i.e. add `--no-save` to the exec calls. However, if you need to save your workspace, remember to `save.image()`.

Comment: I do **never ever** directly edit anything under `/usr/bin` — and strongly discourage you from doing so. That's the system area, "unauthorized personnel is prohibited".

Comment: @ulidtko If it's my system, I'm authorized :) I think the real reason this isn't a good idea is because it's going to get overwritten by future upgrades.

Comment: @MichaelMior well yes, you're absolutely correct; however: humans mess up. All the time. It's simply a guideline; unless you have a good reason, leave `/usr` to robots (I mean, the package managers) since they already manage that area. There're ways to not interfere. Otherwise, you're purposefully seeking adventures.