# How to make q('yes') the default quitting behavior in R using .Rprofile?

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to type `q()` in R and have R quit rather than be prompted as to whether I want to quit.

**Is there some code that I could put into my `.Rprofile` file to make this happen?**

I'd prefer if I didn't have to have a custom function floating around in my workspace.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996090/how-to-disable-save-workspace-image-prompt-in-r

Comment: Mac version of R GUI has this option under Preferences > Startup, too. RStudio > Tools > Options > General > Save workspace .Rdata on exit > "Always" but that might not work if you're actually typing quit.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I agree it is a borderline duplicate. I've modified the question to make it explicit that I'm interested in strategies involving Rprofile. In particular, I like your answer and it was not mentioned on the previous question.

Comment: That's why I answered, it didn't fit the mold. And you specified "when I type q()". Which is different than the other potential answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Rprofile.site file:

```
q <- function(save = "yes", status = 0, runLast = TRUE){
.Internal(quit(save, status, runLast))
#<environment: namespace:base>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using R --vanilla works better

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not sure who you're addressing with this answer; are you commenting on the accepted answer? Or providing some guidance to the original asker? If you're addressing the other answer, this post should be removed as it's not an answer. If you're addressing the question, you should [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60043504/edit) to make it more obvious that you're doing so.