# R function called when pressing Ctrl+D

Tags: r

What function (if any) is called when pressing Ctrl+D to exit R repl? I saw in a few questions, such as:

- [How to disable "Save workspace image?" prompt in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996090/how-to-disable-save-workspace-image-prompt-in-r)
- [Expert R users, what's in your .Rprofile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile)

code that led me to believe it's calling either function `q` or `quit`.

The reason I want to override is to make the pesky:

> Save workspace image? [y/n/c]:

prompt on exit go away. However, overriding the function in `.Rprofile` such as:

```
quit <- function(...) {
  print(1)
}
```

and similarly for `q` did not work - i.e. pressing Ctrl-D did not actually print number 1, went straight to the prompt.

The solutions presented in the above links did not seem to work. R version used:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) -- "Trick or Treat"
Copyright (C) 2012 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Comment: BTW It's high time you upgraded. A lot of R packages will not run under that Jurassic version you're running!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yeah, I know :) Unfortunately, that's the latest available in the repositories at the moment for Xubuntu 13.04 - yeah, need to upgrade that too... :)

Comment: Several years later, is there yet any satisfactory answer to this question?

Answer (score 5):

`Ctrl-D` does not call any function, it is special keyboard interrupt.

Try pressing `Ctrl-D`, then answer `c` for cancel. If you press the up arrow to get the last command, you'll see it's not there.

To override the pesky `Save workspace image? [y/n/c]:`, see the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996090/how-to-disable-save-workspace-image-prompt-in-r):

To summarise you have three options:

Calling `R --no-save` instead of `R`,

Loading the following in the interactive R session (won't work from `.Rprofile`):

```
require(Defaults)
setDefaults(q, save="no")
useDefaults(q)
```

Or put the following in your `.Rprofile`:

```
# Set hook to be run when Defaults is attached
setHook(packageEvent("Defaults", "attach"),
  function(...) { setDefaults(q, save="no"); useDefaults(q) })
# add Defaults to the default packages loaded on startup
old <- getOption("defaultPackages");
options(defaultPackages = c(old, "Defaults"))
```

**EDIT:**

Here's another hack I can think of since the above haven't worked for your case. It's not an R solution, but might do the trick?

First, move you `R` executable file (for the purposes of this example i'm going to assume it's in `/usr/bin/`) to a new file, something like:

`sudo mv /usr/bin/R /usr/bin/Rold`

Now set up a new bash script as `/usr/bin/R`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/Rold --no-save "$@"
```

and `chmod` it to have the right permissions.

Comment: Thanks @Manetheran. AFAIK, Ctrl+D is not an interrupt, it just an EOT character (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-D). So it looks like R is specifically asking for workspace save when EOT is encountered. The .Rprofile suggestion (which I already tried, see the links in my question) doesn't work. The only option that works is using `R --no-save`, however if an external program is running R that's not an option. Is there a pure R solution to this?

Comment: I've added another answer. It's not an R solution, but a hack that should make the external program call `R --no-save`.

Comment: [Package ‘Defaults’ was removed from the CRAN repository.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Defaults/index.html) (in 2014?)