# How to disable source() file echo in R?

Tags: r

According to [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/source), `source()` takes a default option `echo = verbose`, which can get old fast when testing functions. How can I set this to be FALSE just for `source()` in a simple way (such as an .Rprofile setting)?

I tried setting `options(echo=FALSE)` but that throws a wrench in the terminal functioning:

```
> options(echo=FALSE)

5
[1] 5
options(echo=TRUE)
>
```

Comment: Related: [How to disable “Save workspace image?” prompt in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4996090/271616)

Comment: Wow, hairy, but workable!

Comment: By default it's FALSE, right? Are you explicitly setting `options(verbose=TRUE)` for some other purpose?

Comment: `verbose` is default `FALSE`? I don't remember changing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
library(Defaults)
setDefaults("source",echo=FALSE)
```

?

This is similar to (but not quite identical/somewhat simpler than) the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996090/how-to-disable-save-workspace-image-prompt-in-r).

Since the `Defaults` package was archived 6 months after this question was answered, you either would have to get it from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Defaults/Defaults_1.1-1.tar.gz) or use `devtools::install_version("Defaults","1.1-1")`, or fall back to @KonradRudolph's answer.

Comment: For posterity, also note that RStudio assumes that whatever source option you clicked in the sub-menu (with or without echo) is what you would like every time you click the Source button...and thus no option or explanation about this feature, which is what led me to ask this question in the first place.

Comment: No, [Package ‘Defaults’ was removed from the CRAN repository way back on 2014-10-03](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Defaults/index.html)

Comment: OK, but I answered this question 6 months before that!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using RStudio, the Source button can perform either "Source" or "Source with Echo" using the little dropdown arrow to select between then. The button will then continue to run with the last chosen option.

Answer (score 2):

Redefine `source`:

```
source = function (file, local = FALSE, print.eval = echo,
                   verbose = getOption("verbose"),
                   prompt.echo = getOption("prompt"), max.deparse.length = 150,
                   chdir = FALSE, encoding = getOption("encoding"),
                   continue.echo = getOption("continue"), skip.echo = 0,
                   keep.source = getOption("keep.source")) {
    base::source(file, local, echo = FALSE, print.eval, verbose, prompt.echo,
                 max.deparse.length, chdir, encoding, continue.echo, skip.echo,
                 keep.source)
}
```

Terrible, I know. But effective.

Answer (score 0):

No, source does not take a "default option".  It takes a `logical` argument `echo`, which defaults to the value of `verbose`.  If the caller doesn't pass `verbose` either, that argument, in turn, defaults to `getOption("verbose")`.  So if you wanted to set a **global** option to affect echoing of the input text, you would do `options(verbose=FALSE)`.  BTW, that's the setting of this option by default anyway, so you only need to change any of the above if you set it differently.