# problem for R program in VS code (not showing result in terminal )>> R language

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am very new VS code please help me.

Here I am not able getting the result, its showing only the path:
[image: here I am not able getting the result, its showing only the path.]

if I use `view(m)` then its showing the result in a new tab. I have installed the extensions and software correctly. Please help me.

Comment: in R `source()` doesn't print anything. It just runs code. If you want to see what's being run you can use the `echo=` parameter: `source(..., echo=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks MrFlick it work ...but one more thing how do i put echo=TRUE  while writing code in vs editor ... i mean DO i need to put echo=TRUE for every run

Comment: I think the best way is to always explicitly state `echo = TRUE` in your script, but if you don't want to do that, you should be able to change the defaults in the global options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173044/how-to-disable-source-file-echo-in-r