# How to permanently "source" an R script

Tags: r

I am using an R script that someone sent me. This is not a big package but just one function. To use it, I `source` the file.

However,whenever I restart R, I must type in `source("directory")` *again* to use the function.

Is there any way I can avoid this and set that function permanently?

Comment: Another clean way would be to build a package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you just want to add `source("directory")` to your .Rprofile so that the function gets loaded at startup.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189759/expert-r-users-whats-in-your-rprofile) for some handy things you can do with .Rprofile.

Comment: How do you do this for Linux?

Comment: Create a text file called .Rprofile with your commands and save it in your home directory (~).